# Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?

Tags: php, string, numbers, evaluate

I have the following piece of code:

```
$item['price'] = 0;
/* Code to get item information goes in here */
if($item['price'] == 'e') {
    $item['price'] = -1;
}
```

It is intended to initialize the item price to 0 and then get information about it. If the price is informed as 'e' it means an exchange instead of a sell, which is stored in a database as a negative number.

There is also the possibility to leave the price as 0, either because the item is a bonus or because the price will be set in a later moment.

But, whenever the price is not set, which leaves it with the initial value of 0, the `if` loop indicated above evaluates as true and the price is set to -1. That is, it considers 0 as equal to 'e'.

How can this be explained?

When the price is provided as 0 (after initialization), the behavior is erratic: sometimes the if evaluates as true, sometimes it evaluates as false.*

Comment: I found that using triple === instead of double == gives the expected behaviour. But it still is weird.

Comment: *(reference)* sufficiently explained in the PHP Manual at chapter [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and illustrated in the [Type Comparison Table](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Comment: If the only possible string type is 'e', can't you just go for a is_string($item["price"]) check? That would be a little more efficient than ===. [citation needed]

Comment: in **weak comparisons** between string and integer **the string is converted to integer** (instead of the integer being "promoted" to string). `if((string)$item['price'] == 'e')` fixes the odd behaviour. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48912540/1579327 for **more details**

Comment: Please note another case in the comments below by @Paolo where 0 (integer) equals any other string when using the double equals operator.

Comment: In PHP<8 when a string is compared to a number, the string is automatically cast to a number which if non-numeric becomes 0. Starting in PHP 8 though, that is no longer the case because of the weird behavior that you describe. In PHP 8, the 0 is cast to a string, and the comparison is not equal.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You are doing `==` which sorts out the types for you.

`0` is an int, so in this case it is going to cast `'e'` to an int. Which is not parsable as one and will become `0`. A string `'0e'` would become `0` and would match!

Use `===`

From [PHP.net](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/string_to_number_comparison#introduction):

> Comparisons between strings and numbers using == and other non-strict
> comparison operators currently work by casting the string to a number,
> and subsequently performing a comparison on integers or floats. This
> results in many surprising comparison results, the most notable of
> which is that 0 == "foobar" returns true.

However this behavior was changed in [PHP 8.0](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#saner-string-to-number-comparisons):

> When comparing to a numeric string, PHP 8 uses a number comparison.
> Otherwise, it converts the number to a string and uses a string
> comparison.

PHP 7

```
0 == 'foobar' // true
0 == '' // true
4 == '4e' // true (4e is cast as a number and becomes 4)
```

PHP 8 converts numbers to strings before making comparisons

```
0 == 'foobar' // false
0 == '' // false
4 == '4e' // false ('4e' is considered non-numeric therefore 4 is cast as a string and becomes '4')
```

This is a major change therefore it was implemented in a new major PHP version. This change breaks backward compatibility in scripts that depend on the old behavior.

Comment: Another disadvantage of loosy comparison.

Comment: Tricky one. Just bumped into this one and was amazed why string == 0. Gotta remember that.

Comment: Was scratching my head on this one too when I was looping on string keys, but the array had an initial 'zero' index item which kept resulting in true on the first string key compare. I was like what? How in the... so, sure enough, this answer cleared that up! I'm surprised this entire question has not ONE accepted answer. Just goes to show some question askers are jerks.

Answer (score 48):

This is due to how PHP does the comparison operation that the [`==` comparison operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) denotes:

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically. […] The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is `===` or `!==` as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

As the first operand is a number (`0`) and the second is a string (`'e'`), the string is also converted to a number (see also [table *Comparison with Various Types*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.types)). The manual page on the string data type defined how the [string to number conversion](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) is done:

> When a string is evaluated in a numeric context, the resulting value and type are determined as follows.
>
> If the string does not contain any of the characters '`.`', '`e`', or '`E`' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by `PHP_INT_MAX`), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float.

In this case the string is `'e'` and thus it will be evaluated as a float:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be `0` (zero). Valid numeric data is an optional sign, followed by one or more digits (optionally containing a decimal point), followed by an optional exponent. The exponent is an '`e`' or '`E`' followed by one or more digits.

As `'e'` does not start with a valid numeric data, it evaluates to float `0`.

Comment: php designs most everything to be easily comparable and then throws in a few gotchas just to ruin our day.  This is not fit with the rest of PHP's design philosophy.  Unless deception is there philosophy???

Comment: especially since "e" casts to true and "" casts to false

Answer (score 27):

```
"ABC" == 0
```

evaluates `true` because **first** `"ABC"` is converted to integer and becomes `0` **then** it is compared to `0`.

This is an **odd** behaviour of the PHP language: normally one would expect `0` to be promoted to string `"0"` and then compared to `"ABC"` with a result `false`.
Perhaps that's what happen in other languages like JavaScript where the weak comparison `"ABC" == 0` evaluates `false`.

Doing a strict comparison solves the problem:

```
"ABC" === 0
```

evaluates `false`.

But **what if I do need to compare numbers as strings with numbers?**

```
"123" === 123
```

evaluates `false` because the left and right term are of different type.

What is actually needed is a weak comparison without the pitfalls of PHP type juggling.

The solution is to explicit promote the terms to string and then do a comparison (strict or weak doesn't matter anymore).

```
(string)"123" === (string)123
```

is

`true`

while

```
(string)"123" === (string)0
```

is

`false`

---

Applied to the original code:

```
$item['price'] = 0;
/*code to get item information goes in here*/
if((string)$item['price'] == 'e') {
    $item['price'] = -1;
}
```

Comment: cast to string was a big help in my case, thanks!

Answer (score 8):

The == operator will try to match values even if they are of different types. For instance:

```
'0' == 0 will be true
```

If you need type comparison as well, use the === operator:

```
'0' === 0 will be false
```

Answer (score 8):

Your problem is the double equal operator, which will typecast the right member to the type of the left. Use strict if you prefer.

```
if($item['price'] == 'e') {
    $item['price'] = -1;
}
```

Let's go back to your code (copied above). In this case, in most cases, $item['price'] is an integer (except when it is equal to e, obviously). As such, by laws of PHP, PHP will typecast `"e"` to integer, which yields `int(0)`. (Don't believe me? `<?php $i="e"; echo (int)$i; ?>`).

To easily get away from this, use the triple equal (exact comparison) operator, which will check the type and will not implicitly typecast.

P.S: a PHP fun fact: `a == b` does not imply that `b == a`. Take your example and reverse it: `if ("e" == $item['price'])` will never actually be fulfilled provided that $item['price'] is always an integer.

Answer (score 6):

You should use `===` instead of `==`, because the ordinary operator does not compare the types. Instead it will attempt to typecast the items.

Meanwhile the `===` takes in consideration type of items.

- `===` means "equals",
- `==` means "eeeeh .. kinda looks like"

Comment: I see. This now works (with a typecast):
`if((string)$item['price']=='e'){
    $item['price'] = -1;
    }`

Comment: but you should not do that. just use the the `===` operator

Answer (score 6):

There's a rather handy method in PHP for validating a mix of "0", "false", "off" as == false and "1", "on", "true" as == true which is often overlooked.  It's particularly useful for parsing GET/POST arguments:

```
filter_var( $item['price'], FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN );
```

It's not wholy relevant to this use-case but given the similarity and fact this is the result search tends to find when asking the question of validating (string)"0" as false I thought it would help others.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php

Answer (score 4):

Basically, always use the `===` operator, to guarantee type safety.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think it is best to show by examples I did, while running into the same weird behavior. See my test case and hopefully it will help you understand the behavior better:

```
// Normal comparison using the == Operator
echo (0 == "0"); // true
echo (0 == "a"); // true
echo (0 == "safta!"); // true
echo (1000 == "bla"); // false. It appears that PHP has a weird behavior only with the number / string 0 / "0" according to the past 3 examples.
echo (23 == "23"); // true. So as we said, PHP has a problem (not a problem but weird behavior) only when the number / string 0 (or "0") is present
echo (23 == "24"); // false. values aren't equal (unlike last example). The type is less relevant with the == operator as we can see.

// Now using the === and !== Operators
echo ("0" === 0); // false, since === requires both value and type to be the same. Here, type is different (int vs string)
echo ("0" !== 0); // true because they aren't the same in terms of === comparison (type is different and that's why it's true)
echo ("bla" === "blaa"); // false because the values are not the same. The type is the same, but === checks for both equal type and equal value.

//Now using casting and === Operator:
echo ((string)123 === "123"); // true. The casting of the int 123 to string changed it to "123" and now both variables have same value and are of same type
echo ((int)"123" === 123); // true. The casting of the string 123 to int, changed it to int, and now both variables are of same value and type (which is exactly what the === operator is looking for)

// Now using casting and == Operator. Basically, as we've seen above, the == care less for the
// type of var, but more to the value. So the casting is less relevant here, because even
// without casting, like we saw earlier, we can still compare string to int with the == operator
// and if their value is same, we'll get true. Either way, we will show that:
echo ((string)123 == "123"); // true. The casting of the int 123 to string changed it to "123" and now both vars have same value and are of same type
echo ((int)"123" == 123); // true. The casting of the string 123 to int, changed it to int, and now both vars are of same value and type (which is exactly what the === operator is looking for)
```

Comment: Great test, I did the same but I made a nice table from. see my answer