# php string comparasion to 0 integer returns true?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)

I have this piece of code:

```
$o['group'] = "prueba";
if( $o['group'] == 0){
    die("test");
}
```

Why it print test? how can be possible that a string is equal to zero?

Comment: In PHP, the empty string, and the string `"0"` will both be equal to zero with the equality operator (`==`).

Comment: @MichaelMior: And any other string which cannot be converted to a number.

Answer (score 18):

if you want it to exactly match the string try using the exact typof three equal signs like so 
 `if( $o['group'] === 0){`

the `==` will always evaluate to true when comparing a string to a integer of 0

> 'a string' == 0 also evaluates to true because any string is converted into an integer when compared with an integer. If PHP can't properly convert the string then it is evaluated as 0. So 0 is equal to 0, which equates as true.

From [here](http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/string-equals-zero-php-240.html)

Comment: Still wrong. `'0.1e2' == 0` is false although `(int) '0.1e2' === 0` is true. The string content determines which data type (*int* or *float*) the string is converted to.

Comment: Yes, this is still wrong. Only works if $o['group'] == '0'

Answer (score 10):

Use comparison operator with type check "===". Look here for the example http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php and explanation why *non-numerical* string compared to zero always returns `true`.