# IF Statement always executed in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)
>   [php string comparasion to 0 integer returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671942/php-string-comparasion-to-0-integer-returns-true)

it seems that as one has in PHP an if-statement where a function some_function() returns zero

```
<?php
if( some_function() == "whatever_you_want" ) { ... }
```

the statement will always be executed since

```
<?php
echo some_function() == "whatever_you_want";
```

is then TRUE.

Why behaves PHP in such a counter intuitive way?

Comment: What exactly does the function return? "Zero" is not a thing.

Comment: What is the point of comparing an integer (0) to a string? And if you insist on doing so, then use the `===` operator.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [defined behavior of PHP when you compare a number value and a string value](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

> If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is [converted to a number](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) and the comparison performed numerically. These rules also apply to the switch statement. The type conversion does not take place when the comparison is `===` or `!==` as this involves comparing the type as well as the value.

Use strict value comparison with `===` or `!==` and you’re getting the expected result.