# PHP : confused with "==" operator

Tags: php

Can somebody explain to me why this codes returns "TRUE".
I know that i should use the "===" rather "==" but I run to this code and wondering why it returns to true. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    $s = "final";
    $i = 0;
    if($s == $i){
        echo "TRUE";
    }else{
        echo "FALSE";
    }
```

Comment: functions *return* (a value). code *prints* or *echo*es

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do the PHP equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)

Comment: Thanks guys. I learned a lot today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [PHP comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

You can see in the "Loose comparisons with ==" table that comparing the number 0 with a string containing text ("php" in the example) evaluates to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 5):

When you are trying to compare string and number, interpretator converts your string to int, so you got 0 == 0 at final. Thats why `string == 0` is true.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a property of the [loose comparisons](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) implemented in PHP. I wouldn't search for any more logic behind this than that this is a given.

Answer (score 1):

As mentionned above, it is an issue with php's loose comparison. The accepted answer on [php string comparasion to 0 integer returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671942/php-string-comparasion-to-0-integer-returns-true) Explains it well enough IMHO. in short "==" attempts to cast your string into an int, and since it fails, the resulting int has a value of 0

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is **converted to a number** and the comparison **performed numerically**.

And from [PHP string conversion to numbers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion):

The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value **will be 0 (zero)**.

So when you compare integer and a string, PHP tries to convert string to integer first and as "final" doesn't contain any valid numeric data, it is converted to 0.

You can try:

```
var_dump( intval('12final') );      //int(12)
var_dump( floatval('1.2final') );   //float(1.2)
```

This is because of both `12final` and `1.2final` start with valid numeric data (`12` and `1.2` respecrively), their converted value is not 0.