# Why zero (0) and string are the same in PHP?

Tags: php

```
<?php

// your code goes here
if (0 == "asdf")
    echo "same";
else
    echo "not same";
```

Hello, Why this code prints "same", not "not same"? I'm little bit confused about this weird result. Is this a bug?

Execution Result: see http://ideone.com/wfWRlq

Comment: This has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671942/php-string-comparasion-to-0-integer-returns-true

Comment: You can cast the string to int, so that you compare same types

Comment: Because PHP is a terrible excuse for a language. Try Perl

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not a bug the string just get's converted to a int. It converts it from left to right until a non numeric value. So since there is a non numeric value right at the start it gets converted to 0.

For more information about String to int see the manual: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

And a quote from there:

> The value is given by the initial portion of the string. If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. **Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).**

So as an example to show that:

```
echo "5xyz" + 5;  // 5 + 5 -> 10
    //^
echo "xyz5" + 5;  // 0 + 5 -> 5
       //^
echo "x5z"  + 5;  // 0 + 5 -> 5
     //^
```

Comment: "asdf" == 0 returns true too :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `===`. Because that do convert type of value.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of non-intuitive behaviors of comparisons in PHP. There's `==` operator for loose comparison, what checks only values of given variables and `===` operator for strict comparison, what checks also types of variables. PHP manual has [dedicated page with comparisons tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).