# Weird PHP String Integer Comparison and Conversion

Tags: php, string, types, integer

I was working on some data parsing code while I came across the following.

```
$line = "100 something is amazingly cool";
$key = 100;

var_dump($line == $key);
```

Well most of us would expect the dump to produce a `false`, but to my surprise the **dump was a `true`**!

I do understand that in PHP there is type conversion like that:

```
$x = 5 + "10 is a cool number"; // as documented on PHP manual
var_dump($x); // int(15) as documented.
```

But why does a comparison like how I mentioned in the first example converts my string to integer instead of converting the integer to string.

I do understand that you can do a `===` strict-comparison to my example, but I just want to know:

- Is there any part of the PHP documentation mentioning on this behaviour?
- Can anyone give an explanation why is happening in PHP?
- How can programmers prevent such problem?

Comment: == does numerical comparison I think, and when you take and string and convert it to a number if it begins with a number, it uses that number.  If it doesn't probably return something like NaN.

Comment: Most of us would expect this.... when casting a string to an integer (as happens when comparing a string with a number), PHP stops at the first non-numeric digit it encounters, in this case the space between 100 (all digits) and "something". SO 100 is the resultant value.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8672423

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: @mark yes most of us would expect a conversion when performing arithmetical operations, but in a comparison one?

Comment: This is all fully documented in the PHP manual, see the section entitled "String conversion to numbers" on page http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php for details of string->numeric casting, and the table of "comaprison with various types" on page http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php for the explanation that string/numeric comparison converts the string to a numeric

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I recal correcly PHP 'casts' the two variables to lowest possible type.
They call it type juggling.

try: `var_dump("something" == 0);` 
for example, that'll give you true . . had that bite me once before.

More info: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: The PHP manual now describes type juggling at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php which in turn links to a section about string conversion to numbers at http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered and accepted, but I wanted to add something that may help others who find this via search.

I had this same problem when I was comparing a post array vs. keys in a PHP array where in my post array, I had an extra string value.

```
$_POST["bar"] = array("other");

$foo = array(array("name"=>"foobar"));

foreach($foo as $key=>$data){
    $foo[$key]["bar"]="0";
    foreach($_POST["bar"] as $bar){
        if($bar==$key){
            $foo[$key]["bar"]="1";
        }
    }
}
```

From this you would think that at the end `$foo[0]["bar"]` would be equal to `"0"` but what was happening is that when `$key = int 0` was loosely compared against `$bar = string "other"` the result was `true` to fix this, I strictly compared, but then needed to convert the `$key = int 0` into a `$key = string "0"` for when the POST array was defined as `array("other","0");` The following worked:

```
$_POST["bar"] = array("other");

$foo = array(array("name"=>"foobar"));

foreach($foo as $key=>$data){
    $foo[$key]["bar"]="0";
    foreach($_POST["bar"] as $bar){
        if($bar==="$key"){
            $foo[$key]["bar"]="1";
        }
    }
}
```

The result was `$foo[0]["bar"]="1"` if `"0"` was in the POST bar array and `$foo[0]["bar"]="0"` if `"0"` was not in the POST bar array.

Remember that when comparing variables that your variables may not being compared as you think due to PHP's loose variable typing.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but your example is too convoluted for its own good. The issue seems to be that you define `$foo` as an associative array nested within a regular array, but then use the associative array expression `($key=>$data)` to parse the regular array. If you have to have this nesting in the data, why not also nest that loop within another one that would handle the regular array?