# PHP String - int comparison

Tags: php

Anyone know why in php

```
var_dump( "cat" == 0 );
```

Evaluates to true? Also I realize:

```
var_dump( "cat" === 0 );
```

has the intended result, but curious as to why the first case would be true. Also this is php 5.3.

Comment: nvm found the answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9257685/weird-php-string-integer-comparison-and-conversion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP Manual has a type [comparison table](https://www.php.net/types.comparisons) in it, which gives you an idea of what happens when comparing variables of two different data types.

Your first example (a 'loose' comparison since it does not also check the data types of the two operands) implicitly converts the string on the left to an integer.  Since it does not start with a number, the string is converted to the integer 0, which *is equal* to the integer 0.

Your second example compares not only the values but the types as well.  Since the type is different, the comparison is false.

Answer (score 2):

The string is being implicitly converted to an integer. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> If the string starts with valid numeric data, this will be the value used. Otherwise, the value will be 0 (zero).

Answer (score 1):

Because you are implicitly casting the string to an integer, and as the string does not contain numbers it is cast to a 0

Answer (score -1):

"cat" is juggling to 0 as an integer, that is why it is true

but if you typed

```
var_dump( "01" == 0 );
```

it would have been false because 1 is not equals 0

Comment: Your expression actually evaluates to true. `cat1` is converted to `0`. The string needs to *begin* with an integer to be converted into that integer.