# PHP first index gets treated as string

Tags: php

I will keep this brief, this is my code:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    "x" => "aaa", 
    "y" => "bbb"
);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){

    if($k !="y" && $k != "x") {
        echo $v . " ";
    }

}

?>
```

and this is the result:

```
2 3
```

and it acts as though this:

```
$example = 0;
if ($example == 'x' || $example == 'y') {
    echo "true";
}
```

would echo out "true" instead of nothing.

---

Basically, my question is: why does it skip echo-ing out the first element of the array, if 0 does not equal "x" or "y"?

Comment: Reading it back, the title of the question seems very misleading, but i'm not sure what to title it.

Comment: It's an issue with `!=` being more lenient than `!==` because of the `0` value of the key. Try the latter, and you'll get what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php not equal to != and !==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and)

Comment: @aynber Yes, I think it is, but I wasn't sure where the problem was before asking the question, now that I know, I would agree with you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP String - int comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468148/php-string-int-comparison)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `==` sorts out the types for you.

`0` is an `int`, so it is going to cast `y` and `x` to an int. Which is not parseable as one, and will become 0. A string '0x' would become 0, and would match!

Go with `!==`

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bed936181e386ddfe75e4ef92771bf61ad2e7915

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    "x" => "aaa", 
    "y" => "bbb"
);

foreach($arr as $k => $v){

    if($k !=="y" && $k !== "x") {
        echo $v . " ";
    }

}
// result:
// 1 2 3
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6843075/2119863)

Comment: `0` is also a false-y value. I think it's using that more than using casting the letter to an int.

Comment: I wouldn't have answered had I seen this answer, thank you @Unamata Sanatarai. Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

That is a good one, I think I found the fix, instead of using != in both of your evaluations in the if statement, try using !== so, change your if statement to:

```
if($k !== "y" && $k !== "x")
```

See Unamata Sanatarai answer above, explained very well.