# How come ('-' == 0) === true?

Tags: php, casting, type-conversion

I was working here with some exploded string walks:

```
array_walk($data, function(&$value)
{
    // Transform numerics into appropriate type numbers
    if (is_numeric($value))
    {
        $value = substr_count($value, '.') == 1 ? (float) $value : (int) $value;
    }

    // Transform dashes into nulls
    if ($value == '-')
    {
        $value = null;
    }
});
```

to transform values into their appropriate types, and some special character handling.

Where I stumbled upon an interesting, huh, bug?

### The Bug

I was amazed, that each entry, that had it's initial value as `string(1) '0'` ended up being a `null`.

At first, I thought that the problem relies in `(float)` and `(int)` typecasts, though, after debugging:

```
var_dump((float) '0', (int) '0');
```

I saw that's not the case, getting the expected result:

```
float(0)
int(0)
```

It took me a while, to attempt to debug the, *what at the moment appeared to be an obvious*, weak type check, but, once I did, I was shocked:

```
var_dump('-' == 0);
```

The above expression appears to be:

```
bool(true)
```

Now, while writing, I thought I should debug some more, so:

```
var_dump( '=' == 0 );
var_dump( 'What a lovely nonsense?' == 0 );
var_dump( 0 == 'DAFUQ?' ); // maybe it's because of order? It's PHP, world of miracles, you know...
```

And, every expression listed above is `bool(true)`.

Okay, maybe that's because internally, mystically PHP casts the expression into a `(bool)`?

```
var_dump( (bool) '-' == 0 );
```

No:

```
bool(false)
```

### So, so, so...

I made a test-case here: http://codepad.org/smiEvsDj
The problem exists in 5.2.5 (codepad), also in 5.4.3 (friend) and also in 5.4.17 (my actual environment).

What is the reason behind this *feature* / bug / **what-the-F-actually-is-this**?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)

Comment: Just read the [manual pages](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) about loose typing and get over it.... this supposed `issue` with loose-type comparisons has been hashed to death over the years

Comment: `If you compare a number with a string or the comparison involves numerical strings, then each string is converted to a number and the comparison performed numerically.`  [Source](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: I have only one thing to say... *DUCK* PHP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have stumbled upon one of the major complaints that people have about PHP as a language: The fact that the "==" operator is not transitive.

Any string `"foo" == TRUE`, because the PHP people wanted this to work:

```
if ($string) {
    // do something if $string is set
}
```

Yet, converting a string to a number (which PHP always tries to do when you use "=="), `"foo" == 0`!

Of course, `TRUE != 0`. That is a major pain when dealing with PHP, it's not logical, but it's reality.

Answer (score 0):

It's trying to parse numbers from your strings, not finding any digits and automatically reverting to 0.  I think...

e.g. it sees `'What a lovely nonsense?' == 0`, sees that you're comparing integers, and tries to convert `What a lovely nonsense?` to an integer.  As there are no numerical digits it defaults to 0, and believes that LHS == RHS so returns true