# Simple If else is not working

Tags: php, if-statement

```
<?php
    var_dump($isHoster); // prints int(0)

    if ($isHoster == 'all')
        $conditionsHoster = '0, 1';
    else
        $conditionsHoster = intval($isHoster);

    var_dump($conditionsHoster); // prints string(4) "0, 1"
?>
```

What is going on?? Who can explain that?
This never happened to me...

Comment: Relevant manual documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion

Comment: Why? "all" can never be the same as 0.

Comment: It doesn't make any sense, but that's how PHP does it. It's safer comparing things of the same type or using `===` instead.

Comment: That's how PHP rolls. Please take a look at this question and its answers: [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string) - that might give you a better idea.

Comment: okay thanks guys...this destroys my worldview

Comment: Obligatory: http://me.veekun.com/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/

Comment: 'all' is not the `same` as 0 but it does evaluate to 0 when it is type-cast.  `===` checks for `sameness` (type and value).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`0 == 'all'` is true in php because php tries to convert `'all'` to `int` and `(int) 'all'` is `0`; you should write

```
if ($isHoster === 'all')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    var_dump($isHoster); // prints int(0)

    if ($isHoster === 'all')
        $conditionsHoster = '0, 1';
    else
        $conditionsHoster = intval($isHoster);

    var_dump($conditionsHoster);
```

Its because you are comparing Int with String.
Before comparing convert $isHoster to string like $isHoster = (string) $isHoster; or user === to compare.