# Null / Text Values getting treated as "0"

Tags: php, function

I want my function to do the following:

if price is `0`, return `free` message.

If price is positive, show the price.

If price value is unavailable - for example: if the database cell for the price is null, or have a value like `unknown`, then return `unavailable` message.

So I came with this code:

```
function get_rate($foo,$bar) {

  if ($bar== "something") {
    //$test= "testing";
  } elseif ($foo== 0) {
    $message = 'Free';
  }  elseif ($foo> 0) {
    $message = '$'.$foo;
  }  else {
    $message = 'Unavailable';
  }

  return $message;

}
```

HTML:

```
<?= get_rate( $price) ?>
```

But for the values:

`$price="unknown";` or if     `$price` is null, I'm still getting "Free" message.

Comment: Yu're mixing variables here. The input parameters are `$foo`and `$bar`, but you're checking `$bar` and `$a`. please fix your variables.

Comment: already fixed, was typo, thanks.

Comment: @rockyraw you fixed nothing. Why do you even have 2 parameters ?

Comment: @Daan I replaced `$a` with `$foo`, my original code checks 2 parameters, for the sake of the question I removed the second one from question.

Comment: I tested two different $price values, see last line in question.

Comment: Loose comparison using `==`.... string `unknown` is cast to integer for the comparison, and equals `0` whih means `'unknown' == 0` is true.... this is pretty standard type juggling in PHP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does PHP consider 0 to be equal to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

Now you have two solution for this:

**Solution 1:**

```
else if ($foo === 0) // use === for checking value and datatype
```

**Solution 2:**

```
else if ($foo == 0 && $foo != null) // adding != null
```

Value `""` or `null` treated as 0, if you also check the data type using `===` this issue will resolve else use second solution.

---

After your comment, sharing a basic example you will get the idea:

```
$foo = 'bla';
var_dump($foo);
```

It will give you `string(3) "bla"`

Comment: alright, why does text like `$price="bla"` get treated as 0 too, though?

Comment: @rockyraw it feels like explaining too much but just look up == and ===. Having that said I think you know what to do...

Comment: So no matter what I do, `$price="bla"`,`$price=="bla"`,`$price==="bla"`, all are treated as `0`?

Comment: If I use `($foo === 0)`, and `$price="0";` it will return `unavailable` instead of `free`. why? I noticed your #1 solution will work correct only with `=0` rather than `="0"`

Comment: @rockyraw: my friend, i suggest u check this manual link of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php (types comparisons)