# Boolean from MySQL to PHP - Conversion to tinyint and comparing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, boolean

My database has multiple boolean values. After I saved the database, the booleans got converted into tinyint(1). I think this is because it just needs to save 1 or 0.

However, I now have a problem comparing the value in PHP. I saved the tinyint into an array without any code-wise conversion. The array has multiple entries that are text and date and multiple entries with booleans, for example:

```
array[0] is '09:45:00'
array[1] is '10:45:00'
array[2] is 1
array[3] is 0
array[4] is 0
array[5] is 1
array[6] is 'active'
```

Now if I loop through the array I want to check if the value is a time, a text, or true/false.

**Checking if the entry is true will always return true, because no entry is empty. Checking if the entry is 1 or 0 works for the boolean, but when I check if 'active' == 0 it is returning true. Why is this the case and how can I get a false if I compare a string with a tinyint?**

Comparing with === does not work in any case.

Comment: `1 == true` and `0 == false`, using `===` is direct check (so it must match type etc.), using `==` will work for you

Comment: Unfortunately it also returns true if I check 'active' == 0

Comment: You're doing this the wrong way around. The date types are part of the database design and not something you should infer from the query results. All columns might contain a null regardless of type so this will always break down in that case

Comment: @apokryfos So instead of saving 1 or 0, I should save 1 and allow NULL? I'll try that, thanks!

Comment: That's definitely not what I said. I said that if you have a NULL you can't know if that field was a date, number of string normally so you should just know what datatypes your fields are instead of trying to infer them after a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think u can do this with some nested if-else statements. But I'm pretty sure there is a better-looking solution too. :)

```
$a=array('09:45:00','10:45:00',1,0,0,1,'active',3.12);

foreach ($a as $value) {
    $type= gettype($value);
    if ($type == "string") {
        if(strtotime ($value)){
            echo "$value is 'Time' \n";
        }
        else{
            echo "$value is 'String' \n";
        }
    } elseif ($type == "integer") {
        if($value == 0 || $value == 1){
            echo "$value is 'Boolean' \n";
        }
        else{
            echo "$value is 'Integer' \n";
        }
    } else{
        echo "$value is ($type)!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking if the if the value that should be compared is_numeric does work pretty well as a workaround. Still, I'm wondering why 0 == 'string' is true...

Comment: U can find an answer to your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string