# Why this happens in PHP, why it goes inside if statement?

Tags: php

```
<?php
    $st = 'fgh';
    if($st == 1 || $st == 0){
      echo "IN";
    }
?>
```

[Working Example](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xwfxw8nh)

Why This echo IN ??? I'm not able to understand...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string

Comment: Here's the answer from [Sérgio Domingues's post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843030/why-does-php-consider-0-to-be-equal-to-a-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you typecast `$st` to integer and `(int) $st` is equal to `0`.

[Working example](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xwfyg2r5)

Comment: thank you. I wasn't aware of this.