# in_array and multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to do an in_array() on array that will look similar to this,

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 40
            [name] => Simon E Ainley
            [location] => Huddersfield
            [talent] => voice over
            [image] => ./media/uploads/headshots/width_60_249613_10150280293315435_717615434_9570480_8341358_n.jpg
        )

)
```

I am wanting to check if any of the arrays have an `['id']` that matches a var, is in_array() the correct function for this? And can I use it on a multi-dimensional array like the one above?

Comment: possibly dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a specific `id` index specifically, then `in_array()` isn't going to do what you want to do, since that function operates on values rather than keys. That means that if you were searching for a specific id, the function would return true if a different key happened to have the value you were searching for, even if there was no `id` with that value.

If your multidemensional array is always just going to be an array of one dimensional arrays, then you could do something like the following:

```
function find_kv_pair($array, $key, $value) {
  foreach($array as $arr) {
    if ( is_array($arr) && 
         array_key_exists($key, $arr) && 
         $arr[$key] == $value;
       ) {
      return $arr;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

You would then call it like so:

```
 if (find_kv_paid($my_array, "id", 123)) !== false) {
   // do something with the returned array
 } else {
   // nothing found. handle the condition
 }
```

If the array has an array with a key/value pair of `'id' => 123`, then that sub-array would be returned and processed, otherwise you would get a false and you could handle it accordingly.

This function takes your array of sub-arrays, and checks each sub-array to see if it has an `id` key matching your search value. If one is found, it returns that sub-array, or false if no sub-array has it. Modify it to return whatever you like if you don't just want the whole array.

If your sub-arrays can themselves have sub-arrays, you can just rewrite the function to be recursive.