# Detect if a string is in a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
(
    [Product] =>  Amazing Widget
    [Value] => 200
)

[1] => Array
(
    [Product] => Super Amazing Widget
    [Value] => 400
)

[2] => Array
(
    [Product] =>  Promising Widget 
    [Value] => 300
)

[3] => Array
(
    [Product] => Superb Widget
    [Value] => 400
)
)
```

I believe it's a nested Multi-dimensional array.

Anyway I'm trying to detect if a Product Name Already exists in the array.  This is what I'm trying to do

```
if('Super Amazing Widget' is in the array) {
    echo 'In the Array';
}
```

I've tried this:

```
if(in_array('Super Amazing Widget', $array)){
    echo 'In The Array';
}
```

But it's not working and I can't find out why.

EDIT:

Some of the Functions in here worked really well: [in_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: `in_array` won't work the way you want on this array, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`in_array`](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XovZwg) will not do a recursive search, ie, search in sub-arrays. You'll need to loop through your array and manually check for your value.

```
$found = false;
foreach($arr as $item) {
    if ($item['Product'] == 'Super Amazing Widget') {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ($found)
    echo 'found!'; //do something
```

**[Live example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/XovZwg)**

Comment: I was just editing that, was a typo in the question.  The problem is still there.

Comment: @Talon let me cook up another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item["Product"] == "Super Amazing Widget") {
        echo "in the array";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is without using a loop:

```
$filt = array_filter($array, create_function('$val',
                                'return $val["Product"] === "Super Amazing Widget";'));
if (!empty($filt)) {
    echo "In The Array\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using array_filter similar to a previous answer, but using the newer anonymous function instead of the older create_function():

```
if(array_filter(
    $array, 
    function($val) { return $val['Product'] === 'Super Amazing Widget'; }
    )) {
    echo 'In the array' . PHP_EOL;
}
```