# PHP multidimensional array values check

Tags: php, arrays

I'm struggling with some "simple" algorithm for some time now and after searching whole internet for the answer I gave up..... sad, I know. On the beginning I wanted to apologize for my English grammar etc.

Based on this query:

```sql
    SELECT a.*, b.*
    FROM mecze a
    JOIN bets b
    ON a.mecz_id = b.mecz_id AND a.wynik != 'NULL'
```

I have an array "punkty" with such values below:

```
    [0] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 1           //match_id
            [druzyna_1_id] => 1      //team_1_id
            [druzyna_2_id] => 2      //team_2_id
            [wynik] => 1:2           //score - of the match
            [wynik_buk] => 2         //bookie score - of the match
            [bet_id] => 1            //users bet id
            [user_id] => 1           //user id :)
            [bet_wynik] => 3:2       //users bet score
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 1     //users bookie bet score
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0            //points - here will be added when calculated
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 2
            [druzyna_1_id] => 3
            [druzyna_2_id] => 4
            [wynik] => 3:2
            [wynik_buk] => 1
            [bet_id] => 2
            [user_id] => 1
            [bet_wynik] => 3:2
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 1
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 3
            [druzyna_1_id] => 2
            [druzyna_2_id] => 4
            [wynik] => 1:1
            [wynik_buk] => 0
            [bet_id] => 3
            [user_id] => 1
            [bet_wynik] => 1:1
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 0
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 1
            [druzyna_1_id] => 1
            [druzyna_2_id] => 2
            [wynik] => 1:2
            [wynik_buk] => 2
            [bet_id] => 6
            [user_id] => 4
            [bet_wynik] => 3:1
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 1
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 2
            [druzyna_1_id] => 3
            [druzyna_2_id] => 4
            [wynik] => 3:2
            [wynik_buk] => 1
            [bet_id] => 7
            [user_id] => 4
            [bet_wynik] => 2:3
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 2
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 3
            [druzyna_1_id] => 2
            [druzyna_2_id] => 4
            [wynik] => 1:1
            [wynik_buk] => 0
            [bet_id] => 8
            [user_id] => 4
            [bet_wynik] => 0:0
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 0
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 1
            [druzyna_1_id] => 1
            [druzyna_2_id] => 2
            [wynik] => 1:2
            [wynik_buk] => 2
            [bet_id] => 9
            [user_id] => 5
            [bet_wynik] => 1:2
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 2
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 2
            [druzyna_1_id] => 3
            [druzyna_2_id] => 4
            [wynik] => 3:2
            [wynik_buk] => 1
            [bet_id] => 10
            [user_id] => 5
            [bet_wynik] => 3:3
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 0
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [mecz_id] => 3
            [druzyna_1_id] => 2
            [druzyna_2_id] => 4
            [wynik] => 1:1
            [wynik_buk] => 0
            [bet_id] => 11
            [user_id] => 5
            [bet_wynik] => 1:1
            [bet_wynik_buk] => 0
            [krol] => Mario Gomez (GER)
            [laczny] => 5 pkt � Hiszpania ( 2 pkt )
            [punkty] => 0
        )
```

Based on the array above I'm assigning points for getting a good score and exact result:
1 point when a player have correct score (i.e. 1 or X or 2)
4 points when a player have correct exact score (i.e. 1:1 or 3:1 etc.)

```php
    foreach ( $punkty as $k => $v ){
        $wbuk = $v['wynik_buk'];         //match bookie score
        $bwbuk = $v['bet_wynik_buk'];    //users bookie bet score
        $w = $v['wynik'];                //match score
        $bw = $v['bet_wynik'];           //users bet score

        if( $wbuk == $bwbuk ) {
            if ( $w == $bw ) {
                $pkt = 4;
            }else{ 
                $pkt = 1; 
            }
        } else {
            $pkt = 0;
        }
    }
```

The above code is assigning the points correctly but I want to add another thing to it.

I want to add some bonus points for hitting the right score or right exact result if **only one** user has this score/result:
2 points if user is the **only one** with right score (i.e. 1 or X or 2)
1 point if user is the **only one** with right exact result (i.e. 3:1 or 1:1 etc.)

Please help !!! I know that there must be thousand of ways to do it but my mind is in StackOverflow state and crashed :)

Comment: I don't speak Polish so I don't understand what your variables mean.

Comment: "wynik" (result) is the match result i.e. 3:1, 1:1 etc.
"wynik_buk" (bookie result for the match<<i.e. 1, X, 2>>)
"bet_wynik" (bet result) is the users result
----
does it help at all?

Comment: Sorry for that. I'll try to edit the original post and explain the variables

Comment: A round about way would be to do a sql query with count on amount of users that has exact score and if count equals 1 add bonus points.

Comment: Could you give me an example of such query based on above dataset and variables? I have 2 tables (mecze and bets) and 2 variables (mecz_id and user_id) which I have to use. I can't make such query...

Answer (score 0):

Its tricky to give an answer as I can't understand the variables but I think I understand what you want to do.

To tell whether or not the user is the only one with the exact score or the exact result you have a couple of options (well a few but keeping it as simple as possible), run a query on each loop to see if the user is the only one with the correct value or write a function that uses the in_array function:

[in_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Edit:

Or before you get into this loop, run a query and create a 'score' array and manipulate that.