# Find if an array has at least 1 of the values

Tags: php, arrays

I need to find out, in PHP, if an array has any of the values of the other array.

For example :

```
$search_values = array('cat', 'horse', 'dog');
$results = array('cat', 'horse');
if (in_array($search_values, $results))
    echo 'A value was found';
```

Of course, the above does not really work (in_array).

Basically, based on the above example, I want to check if in the **$results** array, there is either a **cat**, **hourse** or a **dog**.

Do I need to do a "foreach" in the 1st array, then do an "in_array" in the 2sd one, and return true; if it is found? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Duplicate of [in_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Duplicate? My question isn't about a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might want to use [array_intersect()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$search_values = array('cat', 'horse', 'dog');
$results = array('cat', 'horse');

if ( count ( array_intersect($search_values, $results) ) > 0 ) {
    echo 'BINGO';
} else {
    echo 'NO MATCHES';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about "array_intersect".

Answer (score 4):

array_intersect() will be slower in some cases with large arrays, because it return whole intersection which is unnecessary. Complexity will be O(n).

Code to just find one match:

```
     $arr1 = array('cat', 'dog');
        $arr2 = array('cow', 'horse', 'cat');

        // build hash map for one of arrays, O(n) time
        foreach ($arr2 as $v) {
            $arr2t[$v] = $v;
        }
        $arr2 = $arr2t;

        // search for at least one map, worst case O(n) time
        $found = false;
        foreach ($arr1 as $v) {
            if (isset($arr2[$v])) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

When using in_array you need to specify as the first value a NEEDLE which is a string.
The second value is the array in which you want to check.

If you want to compare two arrays you need to use array_intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
return !empty(array_intersect($search_values, $result));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `array_intersect` PHP function:

```
<?php

$search_values = array('cat', 'horse', 'dog');
$results = array('cat', 'horse');

$present = array_intersect( $search_values, $results );

if( count( $present ) )
{
    // your code
    echo 'A value was found';
    print_r( $present );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work. My MAMP setup is not on this mac so can't test.

```
$search_values = array('cat', 'horse', 'dog');
$results = array('cat', 'horse');
foreach($results as $k => $v){
 if(in_array($v, $search_values){
    $found = $found && true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code :

```
$search_values = array('cat', 'horse', 'dog');
$results = array('cat', 'horse');
if (count(array_intersect($search_values, $results)) > 0 )
    echo 'A value was found';
```

Use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) function.

Here is the [working demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/goFirK) :