# PHP in_array() not finding value

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [in_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Got the following array returned from a database using this code:

```
$skus = array();
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result){
  while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $skus[]=$rows;
  }
}
```

Results:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array {
            [0] => PUBELI
            [group_sku] => PUBELI
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [0] => PUBESSENTIALS
            [group_sku] => PUBESSENTIALS
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [0] => PUBMGRPROGROUPED
            [group_sku] => PUBMGRPROGROUPED
        )
    [3] => Array (
            [0] => PUB25GROUPED
            [group_sku] => PUB25GROUPED
        )
)
```

I'm looking for this value using in_array:

```
if (in_array('PUBESSENTIALS', $skus))
```

and it returns false. Am I doing this correctly?

Why would the array values not be enclosed in quotes if the values in the DB are strings?

Comment: Look into http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use PHP if you may do something with MySql!
Try this solution:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE str = 'PUBESSENTIALS'"; // some query just add WHERE

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if($result) $Row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $skus is the full array shown above, then 'PUBESSENTIALS' would not be in $skus, because $sku's contains child arrays.

However,  in_array('PUBESSENTIALS', $skus[1])  would return true.

try looping through each $skus element, and then checking that child element for in_array(value, childArray)

Comment: Actually, I did it a different way. I used a where clause in the query and checked the numrows.

Answer (score 1):

You are only looking into the first array, and not any other array. You should look through each to test every sub-array. Something like this could do the job:

```
foreach($skus as $sku) {
    if (in_array('PUBESSENTIALS', $sku)) {
        return true;
    }
}
```