# PHP in_array function not working with multidimensional array in loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that has "formname" in it as a $key.  When I execute the following function:

```
    function in_array_r($needle, $arr, $strict = true) {
    $form_id = $lead['form_id'];
                $user_id = $lead['id'];
                $attachments = array();
$arr=get_defined_vars();
$needle="formna1me";
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            echo "found"; exit;
        }
    }

    echo "notfound"; exit;
}
```

It returns "found" as it should.  But if I change the `$needle` to `$needle = "bbrubrcuyrfbur"` it also returns found.  It is simply always returning found?  Not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Why do you start off with a `foreach()`..?

Comment: Using concept from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Comment: You are using || instead of && in your if statement.

Comment: Added the full function.

Comment: @Jrod - when change to && then it always returns "notfound"

Comment: @Chris sounds like its because the is_array

Comment: @Chris: Please review your code-formatting. It's hard to read and you're asking for help. Give it some love.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function recursively. Even when you call the function with `needle` as `bbrubrcuyrfbur`, in the `if` condition the function is called recursively with `needle` as `formna1me`.

Inside the first recursion, `$arr=get_defined_vars();` will read the value of `$needle` as `formna1me`. Then `$needle` will be reassigned `formna1me` and the `if` condition will match `formna1me` from `$needle` with the one in `$args`.

Lines 2 to 6 should probably not be in that function.

Answer (score 0):

is_array supposed to work like below you are checking the item in is_array instead of array

```
$yes = array('this', 'is', 'an array');

echo is_array($yes) ? 'Array' : 'not an Array';
```

what is_array is doing is that

[`is_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php) — Finds whether a variable is an array

as your comment

tofind that the value is in array try [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) — Checks if a value exists in an array

```
$arr = array("Mac", "NT", "msc", "Linux");
if (in_array("Linux", $arr)) {
   echo 'yes it is';
}
```

Comment: @Chris this is probably one mistake you are doing

Comment: I am not trying to find out if it is an array, I am trying to find if variable is IN an array.