# array_replace() / array_merge() | ( $_SESSION = array() ) argument is not an array?

Tags: php, arrays, session, session-variables

I have this code for my school project and thought the code does its job on what i wanted it to do, i still keep on getting the error about $_SESSION[] is not an array argument when using the `array_replace()` and `array_merge()` functions:

Session is already initiated on the header:

```
 // Start Session
 session_start();
```

For initialising the `$_SESSION['cart']` as an array:

```
// Parent array of all items, initialized if not already...
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
```

For adding products from a dropdown menu: - (Just to see how the session is assigned:)

```
if (isset($_POST['new_item'])) { // If user submitted a product
 $name = $_POST['products']; // product value is set to $name

// Validate adding products:
if ($name == 'Select a product') { // Check if default - No product selected
    $order_error =  '<div class="center"><label class="error">Please select a product</label></div>';
} elseif (in_array_find($name, $_SESSION['cart']) == true) { // Check if product is already in cart:
    $order_error = '<div class="center"><label class="error">This item has already been added!</label></div>';
} else {
    // Put values into session:
    // Default quantity = 1:
    $_SESSION['cart'][$name] = array('quantity' => 1);
       }
}
```

Then here is where the issue comes, when they try to update the product:

```
// for updating product quantity:
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
// identify which product to update:
$to_update = $_POST['hidden'];
// check if product array exist:
if (in_array_find($to_update, $_SESSION['cart'])) {
    // Replace/Update the values:
    // ['cart'] is the session name
    // ['$to_update'] is the name of the product
    // [0] represesents quantity
    $base = $_SESSION['cart'][$to_update]['quantity'] ;
    $replacement = $_SESSION['cart'][$to_update] = array('quantity' => $_POST['option']);
    array_replace($base, $replacement);
    // Alternatively use array merge for php < 5.3
    // array_merge($replacement, $base);
    }
}
```

Note that both the functions `array_replace()` and `array_merge()` are updating the values and doing what the initial goal was, but the problem is that i still keep on getting that one argument(`$base`) is not an array issue.

Warning: array_replace() [function.array-replace]: Argument #1 is not an array in ...

any suggestions for a better way to approach this issue would be a valuable help :)
Thanks for your help :)

Edit: The `in_array_find()` is a function that i use in replacement of `in_array()` as it doesn't apply to finding values in a multi-dimensional array: specifically 2 depth arrays:

found it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array) and it works for me

The code for it is:

```
// Function for searching values inside a multi array:
function in_array_find($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
foreach ($haystack as $item => $arr) {
    if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
        return true;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `in_array_find()`. Is that your own function or did you mean `in_array()`?

Comment: Thanks. @showdev I have added the code for that function :) , i am using it in replacement of the `in_array()` for multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. What do you get if you `echo"<pre>";print_r($_SESSION);echo"</pre>";` before the error?

Comment: First i get this when there is no submission yet `[cart] => Array()` = for cart and when i update the value i get this `(
                    [quantity] => 1
                )))` = where the error comes out. - It does update the cart and replace the value , but theres also the said error coming with it thought the cart has been updated

Comment: Are you doing `session_start()` at the top of your page?

Comment: Thanks. Yep, its initialised in the header and included in every page.

Comment: Maybe it should be `$_SESSION['cart'][$to_update]['quantity']` instead of `$_SESSION['cart'][$to_update][0]`?

Comment: @showdev .. thanks, i tried it but still give the same error..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) returns the replaced array. So you need to do:

```
$base=array_replace($base, $replacement);
```

Also, I suggest using named keys consistently throughout, as opposed to mixing named and numeric:

```
$base = $_SESSION['cart'][$to_update]['quantity'];
```

**EDIT:**

This may not be exactly what you're going for...

I set up a test situation without using $_SESSION, and I got the same error you did. I changed the code as follows and no longer get the error.

```
$sesh=array(
    'cart'=>array(
        0=>array(
            'quantity'=>1
        )
    )
);

$to_update=0;
$new_quantity=5;

//$base = $sesh['cart'][$to_update]['quantity']; <--- changed this to line below
$base = $sesh['cart'][$to_update];

$replacement = $sesh['cart'][$to_update] = array('quantity' => $new_quantity);
$base=array_replace($base, $replacement);

echo"<pre>";print_r($base);echo"</pre>";
```

PHP FIDDLE: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mvr-shr

Comment: Thank you, yup i have updated my code to an associative value as i only used the[0] when i was debugging a diff issue earlier and forgot to change it. hehe. :) btw, i have tried the `$base=array_replace($base, $replacement);` but still gives me the same error.

Comment: @GitKidd I have updated my answer with a test scenario. I got the same error you did and was able to get rid of it. The code is changed a bit so as not to use $_SESSION, but I'm sure you can apply the concept to your own code.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried a more bit by bit analysis and i managed to solve the problem. hehe. kindly have a look at the answer , hope it provides help for future reference too. :)

Comment: Your answer seems the same as my edit. Anyway, I'm glad you got it working!

Comment: +1 for all the help.. your a real star! :) hope i can run to u again if ever i get any future problems.. hehe! :) cheers showdev! ur a genius.

Answer (score 1):

This have solved this issue:

Basically as per the structure: (Lets slice it into bits)

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
```

then

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$name] = array('quantity' => 1);
```

finally:

```
$base = $_SESSION['cart'][$to_update]['quantity'] ;
$replacement = $_SESSION['cart'][$to_update] = array('quantity' => $_POST['option']);
array_replace($base, $replacement);
```

The reason why it says that the argument `$base` is not an array is because:

`['quantity']` in `$base` is not an array as it forms the `'quantity' => 1` what we need is the `array()` value from the `array('quantity' => 1);` for it to be identified as an array.

So final answer should be: `$base = $_SESSION['cart'][$to_update];`
as there is only one `array()` recorded in where the `$to_update` resides so the replacement argument shall replace this identified array.

Comment: How is this different from my edited answer? +1 Good explanation of what was going wrong, though.

Comment: Sorry, just realised as i went to eat dinner then while eating realised this situation, then i tried answering it just after my local test and didn't notice the answer that you edited your answer as i started writing the answer as soon as i got back :) , im giving u the answer point as you've been really helping me from the start. :)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SESSION` only exists when a [Session starts](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php). In order to do that you need to add on top of all your code `session_start()` otherwise the session will not start, unless you define it on [php directives](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.auto-start).

Comment: I have already have the `session_start()` first thing in my page as there are other sessions that are used in other pages (eg: login / admin) = u can only access this specific page if you are logged in, so u are redirected to a different page if your session is false according to your login credentials. also if i `var_dump ($_SESSION)` it shows me all the current sessions.

Comment: try this and see the output, this way you can understand the data.

    `if(is_array($base)){
        $base=array_replace($base, $replacement);
    } else {
        var_dump($base); //or echo the value
    }`