# Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array

Tags: php, arrays

Please take a look to my code below .

```
    $referenceTable = array();
    $referenceTable['val1'] = array(1, 2);
    $referenceTable['val2'] = 3;
    $referenceTable['val3'] = array(4, 5);

    $testArray = array();

    $testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val1']);
    var_dump($testArray);
    $testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val2']);
    var_dump($testArray);
    $testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val3']);
    var_dump($testArray);
```

I was trying to work with two arrays as you can see and while trying to merge the empty array with the older ones i am getting the warnings as

```
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #2 is not an array
Warning: array_merge(): Argument #1 is not an array
```

The Output which i get is

```
array(2) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) }
NULL
NULL
```

I am unable to fix this thing , help appreciated .

Comment: But $referenceTable itself is an array

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245377/array-replace-array-merge-session-array-argument-is-not-an-arr?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245377/array-replace-array-merge-session-array-argument-is-not-an-arr?rq=1)

Comment: array_merge needs both parameters to be array

Comment: and after 2nd call of array_merge, $testArray is null, not an array too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All arguments passed to `array_merge()` need to be arrays and `$referenceTable['val2']` is not an array it is integer `3`.  You can cast it to an array:

```
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, (array)$referenceTable['val2']);
```

Or put it in an array `[ ]`:

```
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, [ $referenceTable['val2'] ]);
```

Or if you're actually defining that variable:

```
$referenceTable['val2'] = array(3);  // or [3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`$referenceTable['val2']` is an int not an array, declare $referenceTable like this to be array :

**PHP**

```
$referenceTable['val2'] = [3];
```

that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking this down

```
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val2']);
```

The problem here is that

```
$referenceTable['val2'] = 3;
```

`3` is not an array. Set it to an array and it works

```
$referenceTable['val2'] = array(3);
```

As to why this fails

```
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, $referenceTable['val3']);
```

You ran the previous statement, which set `$testArray` to `NULL`, which is also not an array

Comment: Yeah Thanks i got it this time

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I was able to resolve this issue and it occurred when I tried to do composer update. 
The command did not work and it only corrupted the Service.json file in

```
/var/www/html/app/storage/meta
```

So what you need to do is to delete the service.json file and replace it with the new one or you do the composer install command.

The website now runs well on https://www.codemint.net

Answer (score -2):

`$referenceTable['val2']` is not an array it is integer 3.

You can cast into an array or multiple arrays:

```
$testArray = array_merge($testArray, array($referenceTable['val2']));
```