# in_array() for array of array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a function like `in_array()` than can, check conntent inside array of arrays?

I tried:

```
$day_events = Array();
array_push($day_events,array('aa','bb','cc'));
array_push($day_events,array('aa','bc','cd'));
array_push($day_events,array('ac','bd','ce'));
echo '<br />';
echo in_array('aa',$day_events); // empty
echo '<br />';
foreach ($day_events as &$value) {
    echo in_array('aa',$value); // 11
}
```

first in_array() which is the kind of function I am looking for (avoiding the loop) gave empty.

Comment: The `in_array()` native PHP function simply doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: @MackieeE, ok. Hmmm... is there another function for that or do I have to live with the for loop?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Rikard Yes, you would and I really wouldn't be bothered by the nano-seconds of performance as an effect =)

Comment: @Rikard Secondly, if you truly wanted to avoid looping at all, you'd make an separate multi-dimensional array that only ever contained 'aa' in first place at the point of array_pushing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function, as [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) doesn't natively support multi-dimensional arrays:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

In this case you would you use it like this:

```
echo in_array_r('aa', $day_events) ? 'Found' : 'Not found';
```

It was taken from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128377/2612112.

Answer (score 0):

By the way it is not avoiding first one it is avoiding the last one which has 'ac'. So you get true from first two. Your code works but I am not sure if that is what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What I want is to check thru the multi-dimensional array. Check all values inside it agains my value. I can do it with for loop and works, but was looking for a function to do this.