# check value if array and array within arrayis existing

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I can check if the value is within the 'Users' but I can't check if the value is within 'Pages'
How it will work both Users and Pages?

```
$mypages = array(
'Pages' => array('pages' => array('add_page', 'edit_page')),
'Users' =>array('view_all_users', 'add_user'));

foreach($mypages as $keys => $key):
    $display = in_array($_GET['page'], $key) ? "block" : "none";
    echo '<ul style="display:'.$display.';"></ul>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should do:

```
    if(is_array($key) && array_key_exists('pages', $key)) {
    $display = in_array($_GET['page'], $key['pages']) ? "block" : "none";
} else {
    $display = in_array($_GET['page'], $key) ? "block" : "none";
}
```

Comment: @user4035 I missed a part of question. Edited answer does it for both!

Comment: it works.. thank you.. is there any other simplification for this? so that I can add more array

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
 foreach($mypages as $keys => $key):
   $display ='none';
       if(!is_array($key)){
           $display = in_array($_GET['page'], $key) ? "block" : "none";
        }else{
            $display = in_array($_GET['page'], $key['indexname']) ? "block" : "none";
        }
        echo '<ul style="display:'.$display.';"></ul>';
 endforeach;
```