# Checking if a multidimensional array contains a specific value

Tags: php, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array("description" => "old, white, brown_hair", "name" => "jacques"),
    [1] => array("description" => "young, black, black_hair", "name" => "jack")
);
```

Now I want to check if the array contains `jack`. I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array).

And [this is my code](https://eval.in/142744).

Comment: You have an array of arrays. Simply loop through them and check if each sub-array has a `name` key with the value `jack`, and if so print it and stop the iteration. See [demo](https://eval.in/142739).

Comment: The recursive function in the other question should have worked as well: `$containsJack = in_array_r('jack', $array);`. See [demo](https://eval.in/142741).

Comment: https://eval.in/142744 @AmalMurali

Comment: @user3578281, Can you just post the `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of your array ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran It is being dynamically generated.

Comment: @user3578281: The code you posted wouldn't likely generate the array shown in question. You're not even using the `in_array_r()` function in your code. I'd suggest that you: 1) Verify that array looks likeyou want it to. `var_dump()` the array to make sure it looks like what you think it does. 2) Use `in_array_r()` on the array (as shown in my second comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple `foreach`

```
foreach($arr as $k=>$arr1)
{
 if(in_array('jack',$arr1))
  {
    echo 'jack exists ! exiting....';
    break;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://eval.in/142740)</kbd>

Comment: This is my code: https://eval.in/142744. And sorry, it didn't seem to work??

Comment: I am just curious , you just want to check if the name is inside the array ? If found , what you wanna do next ?

Comment: Is there any other way to check that multidimensional array contains specific value and it equel some value without foreach loop?