# Php, in_array with no exactly match

Tags: php, arrays

I want to do the following:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = array(1,2);
$a[] = array(2,5);
$a[] = array(3,4);
var_dump (in_array(array(2,5), $a));
```

this returns OK, as it expected, but if the source array is not fully matched:

```
$a = array();
$a[] = array(1,2, 'f' => array());
$a[] = array(2,5, 'f' => array());
$a[] = array(3,4, 'f' => array());
var_dump (in_array(array(2,5), $a));
```

it returns false. Is there a way to do it with the built-in way, or I have to code it?

Comment: why not: var_dump(in_array(2, $a) && in_array(5, $a))

Comment: that wont take the orders into account. Would be true for 2,5 and 5,2

Comment: that will not work at all. First approach checks if there are `array` as element in `$a`, and if it is with values `2, 5`. But separately `2` and `5` are not into `$a` because `$a` is represented as `$a = array(1 = > array(2, 5, 'f'))`

Comment: `in_array` won't do it. It's simply not in the scope of what it does. You'll have to loop yourself.

Comment: [this function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array#answer-4128377) might get you started

Comment: @verbumSapienti not sure it will work for that particular case

Comment: @Royal it should with some tweaking

Answer (score 2):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/in_array) is just not the thing that you should use for this issue. Because it will compare values with type casting, if that's needed. Instead, you may use plain loop or something like:

```
function in_array_array(array $what, array $where)
{
   return count(array_filter($where, function($x) use ($what)
   {
      return $x===$what;
   }))>0;
}
```

So then

```
var_dump(in_array_array(array(2, 5), $a)); //true
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$needle = array(2, 5);
$found = array_reduce($a, function ($found, array $array) use ($needle) {
    return $found || !array_diff($needle, $array);
});
```

This does an actual test of whether the needle is a subset of an array.

```
function subset_in_array(array $needle, array $haystack) {
    return array_reduce($haystack, function ($found, array $array) use ($needle) {
        return $found || !array_diff($needle, $array);
    });
}

if (subset_in_array(array(2, 5), $a)) ...
```