# Match a string with a value in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Here's my array: $properties
Here's a print_r of my array:

```
Array (
 [ID] => 6585
 [ancestors] => Array ( 
   [0] => 6163
 )
```

Here's a variable I want to see if is in my array: `$pageid`

What's a function that will return true if `$pageid == 6163` (the `[0]` element in ancestors)?

Comment: Your terms are a little ambigous - _is in my array_ is a little different from `$pageid == 6163, the [0] element`. Can `ancestors` be multiple elements and you want to know if `$pageid` is one among many, or must `$pageid` be the `[0]` element only?

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I want to see if it is in the subarray, I don't care if it's in the top level array; does that make sense?

Comment: `$bool = in_array($pageid, $properties['ancestors']);`

Comment: in_array doesn't work with multidimensional arrays :( and re: that link, it might work but that function searches every element in the array for the string. I know exactly which element I want to search for the string.

Comment: Michael, ancestors will only ever be one element; I know that makes it pointless that it should be an array, but I can't change that.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_search(6163,$properties['ancestors'],TRUE);
```

Comment: in my script, echo $pageid shows 6163
and [ancestors] => Array ( [0] => 6163 is showing. They match, but I still can't get a return of true

Comment: <?php 
if(array_search($pageid,$properties['ancestors'],TRUE)): ?>
class="quickmovein" 
<?php endif; ?>>  isn't putting the class attribute in my html

Comment: why you dont use this:  if($properties['ancestors'][0] === $pageid)

Comment: markoCarbo yes that works! My array is $property not $properties and that why some of the other solutions may not have worked; sorry if I wasted anyones time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you know exactly which element you want to search, try

```
If(array_key_exist('ancestors',$properties) && is_array($properties['ancestors']) && array_key_exist(0,$properties['ancestors'])){
    return ($properties['ancestors'][0] == 6163);
}else{
    return false;
}
```

I might have misunderstood your question and replies, coz its seems simple to me.

anyway if you explain a bit more I can make my answer better.