# Check if array value exists in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array) and it answered part of my question, but no matter what I do to modify the function, I'm not getting the expected results.

I want to pass an array to this function and check if a value of this array, exists in the multidimensional array. How can I modify this function to work if `$needle` is an `array`?

```
//example data
$needle = array(
    [0] => someemail@example.com,
    [1] => anotheremail@example.com,
    [2] => foo@bar.com
)

function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

**EDIT**

After reading the answer supplied by TiMESPLiNTER I updated my function as follows and it works perfectly.

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (is_array($needle) && is_array($item)) {
            if(array_intersect($needle,$item)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Check if [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-intersect.php) returns an array with at least one element. If yes one of your values in the `$needle` array is contained in the `$haystack` array.

Comment: Your needle is an array and the function you have cannot cope with that. First of all you need to clarify what you want. If the needle is an array, can it be a part of an array, or should it be a whole array as such. I know this might be difficult to understand, but please think about this carefully. The first is more difficult to do than the second.

Comment: Could you give us an example of your multid array?

Comment: PLEASE make your comment an answer @TiMESPLiNTER because that works like a bomb...

Comment: There you go. Probably you can insert your working code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) returns an array with at least one element. If yes one of your values in the `$needle` array is contained in the `$haystack` array.

I ended up with this function:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack) {
    $flatArray = array();

    array_walk_recursive($haystack, function($val, $key) use (&$flatArray) {
        $flatArray[] = $val;
    });

    return (count(array_intersect($needle, $flatArray)) > 0);
}
```

You may extend this function to accept multidimensional arrays for both `$needle` and `$haystack`.

Comment: I've updated the question with my code that works, if you want to have a read through it and maybe suggest improvements