# How to apply in_array for mutidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$categories => Array([0] => Jewelry & Accessories,[1] => Pet Care)
$categories_master => Array([0] => Jewelry & Accessories,[1] => Apparel,[2] => Beauty & Fragrance)
```

I have two arrays like above,

I have to check like this `in_array($categories,$categories_master)`, I know it wont work but I need to return 1 or true for anyone match with `$categories_master` array

Comment: Can you better describe the output you want to receive? [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) may be very close to what you need.

Comment: I need true or false like in_array output

Comment: At least one item match with master category

Comment: So if any one item matches, return `true`? Use `array_intersect()` and verify that the `count() >= 1`

Comment: It seems you are not really asking about multidimensional arrays, but rather multiple 1-dimension arrays.

Comment: To avoid confusion, can you please specify what the output should be for your example above? Should it be `true` or `array(true, false)`

Comment: ^^ or something else entirely...

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @SimplyDread Nope, that isn't what's being asked, despite the title

Comment: Thanks  Michael Berkowski I did with  array_intersect()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the [array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) ( returns an array containing all the values of `$categories` that are present in `$categories_master` ), and cast to boolean. If return array has items it will return true, or false otherwise.

```
(bool) array_intersect( $categories, $categories_master );
```

Also this will evaluate to `true` if the returned array is not empty, `false` for empty array:

```
if(array_intersect( $categories, $categories_master )) {
    //there are one or more matches
}
```