# PHP in_array does not check all cases

Tags: php, arrays

I'm removing values from an array in PHP use an `in_array` check yet for some reason it does not want to check through the entire length of the `exclude array`. Running this code it removes the Dodge entries from the array but not the Toyota, why is this?

```
<?php

    $inventory = array(
        '0' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Dodge',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'B41',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '1' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Dodge',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'B41',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '2' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Dodge',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'B41',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '3' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Dodge',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '4' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '5' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '6' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '7' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '8' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '9' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '10' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'
            ),

        '11' => Array
            (
                'car_name' => 'Toyota',
                'set_name' => 'A',
                'edition' => 'VarA31',
                'location' => 'Houston'

            ),
    );

    $exclude = array('Dodge','Toyota');

    for($k=0; $k<sizeof($inventory); $k++)
    {
    if(in_array(trim($inventory[$k]['car_name']), $exclude))
    {   unset($inventory[$k]);}

    }

         $inventory = array_values($inventory);
         echo '<pre>';
         print_r($inventory);
         echo '</pre>';



    ?>
```

Comment: in_array() does not work on multidimensional arrays.  Possible duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @user2058037 - in_array is being used on the $exclude array here, where it will work

Comment: This is a good example of why incremental `for` loops are not often used in languages supporting some kind of `foreach` construct. If you did this via `foreach ($inventory as $k => $v)` you'll find it much easier to manage.

Comment: think of it this way - if you have to _"do a thing N times"_, use an incremental `for` loop. If you have to _"do a thing to each element in a collection"_, choose a `foreach` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that unsetting an element from an enumerated array will adjust the size of your array, but testing using `sizeof()` to see if you should exit your loop, so each iteration where you unset will reduce the number of values left to test.

```
$exclude = array('Dodge','Toyota');

$size = sizeof($inventory);
for($k=0; $size; $k++) {
    if(in_array(trim($inventory[$k]['car_name']), $exclude)) {
        unset($inventory[$k]);
    }
}

$inventory = array_values($inventory);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($inventory);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are removing the index:value pair from the array, while iterating it. So after unsetting a value the index positions dont match or even exist.

Try copying the values you do need, into a new empty array like this:

```
$exclude = array('Dodge','Toyota');
$filtered = array();

for($k=0; $k<sizeof($inventory); $k++){
    if(in_array(trim($inventory[$k]['car_name']), $exclude)){
        // dont do this because it is changing the count of elements in the array unset($inventory[$k]);
    } else {
        $filtered[] = $inventory[$k]; // push the desired values into a new array
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($filtered);  // this should have the values that don't have 'Dodge' or 'Toyota'
echo '</pre>';
```

**Edit:** Mark's answer would be the best way to go cause it is also better performance wise

Comment: Unsetting an array index in PHP has no effect on the numbers of subsequent indexes.

Comment: It's the `sizeof()` at fault.

Comment: yeah, after unsetting, the recalculation of sizeof() in the loop gets messed up

Answer (score 1):

use `foreach` instead `for($k=0; $k<sizeof($inventory); $k++)`:

```
foreach($inventory as $k => $row)
```

this is because while you are unsetting `$inventory` you skip elements

`$k` = 0, `sizeof($inventory)` = 12, you unset one of the items, `$k++`. `$inventory[1]` becomes `$inventory[0]`

`$k` = 1, `sizeof($inventory)` is now 11, you check `$inventory[1]` but not `$inventory[0]` (previous known as `$inventory[1]`)