# PHP: Using in_array with __set method

Tags: php

I am unable to match a key in an array using `in_array`, contrary to what I expect.

The array I am attempting to match is part of the `_props` array, created using the magic method `__set()`.

The following code returns the response `Incorrect result`. Here is the code, I hope that it's fairly self-explanatory.

```
class foo{

    private $_props;

    public function __set($name, $val){
            $this->_props[$name] = $val;
    }

    public function test(){

            $md_array = array(
                    1 => array(0 => '0', 1 => '1'),
                    2 => array(0 => '0', 1 => '1'),
                    3 => array(0 => '0', 1 => '1')
            );

            $this->__set('test', $md_array);

            if(in_array(1, $this->_props['test'])){
                    echo "Correct result";
            }else{
                    echo "Incorrect result";
            }
   }
}
$a = new foo();
$a->test();
```

Can anyone explain this behaviour for me and offer an alternative?

if I `var_dump $this->_props` I get the following response:

```
array
  'test' => 
    array
      1 => 
        array
          0 => string '0' (length=1)
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => 
        array
          0 => string '0' (length=1)
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
      3 => 
        array
          0 => string '0' (length=1)
          1 => string '1' (length=1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you are testing the value `this->_props['test']` which is whatevery you assined to foo->test but it is NOT an array at the first place

Comment: Thanks, but this works `var_dump($this->_props['test'][1]);`. It gets the correct key and val??

Comment: Well - the array $this->_props is dynamical. We dont know what is in there. Can you pls add which $value is added under the $key test?

Comment: I've added to the original

Comment: btw why you are using magic function to set some array values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) looks in the values of the array. As I understand it, you want to search the keys, you wanna use [`array_key_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
        if(array_key_exists(1,$this->_props['test'])){
                echo "Correct result";
        }else{
                echo "Incorrect result";
        }
```

you should get the right result. If you're meaning to look for the values *recursively*, consider using [array_find()](http://bran.name/dump/array-find-case-insensitive-array-search-with-partial-matches/)

Comment: hes searching in `this->_props` and not in `md_array`. Your answer would be right, if it would be the `md_array`

Comment: `$this->_props = ['test'=>$md_array]` so basically he is, just a level above.

Answer (score 0):

you have a multidim array, and so in_array will not work for you.
you need an own function:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

and in your code:

```
if(in_array_r(1, $this->_props['test'])){
                    echo "Correct result";
            }else{
                    echo "Incorrect result";
            }
```

look here:
[in_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: $this->props is NO multidimensional array

Comment: in my test it is: `print_r($this->_props['test'])` is : `Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) [3] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 ) )`