# Multidimensional Array Search

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [6] => 2015-02-27 19:00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [6] => 2015-02-27 20:00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [6] => 2015-02-27 21:00
        )

)
```

The "6" is a category and I want to check if the category exists with the according date.

I have

```
$category = 7;
$datetocheck = "2015-02-27 20:00"
```

The function should return false.
If I have

```
$category = 6;
$datetocheck = "2015-02-27 20:00"
```

The function should return true.

This https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456356/1092632 looks like what I want to do, but I can't get it to work. Maybe it's not a fitting function.

Any hint/help highly appreciated.

//EDIT
I used this function (from above Post)

```
function in_multiarray($elem, $array,$field)
{
    $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
    $bottom = 0;
    while($bottom <= $top)
    {
        if($array[$bottom][$field] == $elem)
            return true;
        else 
            if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field]))
                if(in_multiarray($elem, ($array[$bottom][$field])))
                    return true;

        $bottom++;
    }        
    return false;
}
```

But when I use it

```
in_multiarray("2015-02-27 20:00",$myArray,6)
```

I get undefined index errors.
I tried "in_array()" but this gives me true for 6 AND 7.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is your own finding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out :

```
$array = array(
        array(6 => '2015-02-27 19:00'),
        array(6 => '2015-02-27 20:00'),
        array(6 => '2015-02-27 21:00'));


    function search_in_array($search_in, $search_for){
        foreach($search_in as $arr){
            if(array_key_exists($search_for[0], $arr) 
                && in_array($search_for[1], array_values($arr)))
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    var_dump(search_in_array($array, array(6, '2015-02-27 19:00')));
```

Comment: thanks for the downvotes from the others and truly thank you for the answer!