# find items in array and delete them if they exist

Tags: php, arrays

i have this items in array

`Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 0001 [1] => 1 [2] => 123456789 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 0000 [1] => 1 [2] => 011155555 ) )`

so, now i want to find `0000` and `011155555` and if they exist to delete that position where they exist.

i cant figure it out how to check if both criteria exist in array. I tried with 'array_search' but i dont know how to search both criteria in array.

so it should be something like that:

if `0000` and `011155555` exist in array, remove that position

Comment: can you give me example, pls?

Comment: Since you're looking at an array of arrays, this sounds like a job for recursion.

Comment: Example of what? `in_array` function? You have no google there?

Comment: @u_mulder `in_array` won't work in this instance as OP is using multi-dimensional arrays... `in_array` only searches 1 dimension arrays

Comment: @gandrap Try looking at this, this is an example of a recursive function searching multidimensional arrays. http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128377/1729859

Comment: @u_mulder i ask you nicley, dont need to be smart guy... i tried in_array aleady, but id doesnt work in my case, or i dont know how to do it.

Comment: @mituw16 thank you for effort, i tried function from link, it work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my second `array_filter()` today:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($v) {
                                    return !(in_array('0000', $v) &&
                                             in_array('011155555', $v));
                               });
```