# Php in_array find value by key

Tags: php, arrays, cycle

I have an array like this:

```
$array = Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 6 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 123 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 123 ) )
```

In a cycle I use the function

```
$id = 123;

if (in_array($id, $array)) {
   echo "found!!";
   }
   else
   {               
   echo "not found";
   }
```

But doesn't works; Why?

Comment: You have nested arrays, ``in_array()`` will not check the contained arrays recursively.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will not work because `$array` contains `array`s as values. `in_array` alone will not help here. Use `array_column` & `in_array` together.

```
in_array($id, array_column($array, 'id'))
```

Comment: Which version you are using? For lesser versions you may\ need to use a loop.

Comment: Now I use the 5.3; I would like to avoid nested cycles

Comment: Always prefer to use latest versions. :)

Answer (score -1):

Just try

```
if (array_search($id,$a)) {
   echo "Found";
} else {
   echo "Not Found"
}
```