# Find array values within Multidimensional array

Tags: multidimensional-array

```
<?php
function multi_array_search($search_for, $search_in) {
    foreach ($search_in as $element) {
        if ( ($element === $search_for) || (is_array($element) && multi_array_search($search_for, $element)) ){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
$arr = array("2014", array("January", "February", "March"), "2015", array("Monday", "Tuesday"));
echo multi_array_search("Tuesday", $arr) ? 'Found' : 'Not found';
?>
```

In the above code
In `multi_array_search("Tuesday",$arr);`
we are passing first parameter is `value` and second parameter is an `array`,
But my query is that we are passing first parameter is a set of values.

i.e. we are taking`$array=array("2015","Tuesday","March");` Like this and when we found matching values then return 'Found' otherwise return 'Not found' also the value may be case-sensitive,

Comment: Just replacing `if ( ($element === $search_for) ...` with `if (in_array($element, $search_for) ...` should work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: we get the required O/P,

Comment: Thanks of your valuable support

Answer (score 0):

Converting the the arguments to lowercase by using **strtolower()** function of PHP makes this job done. The code I come up with is as below, I hope it helps you.

```
<?php
function multi_array_search($search_for, $search_in) {
$search_for=strtolower($search_for);
foreach ($search_in as $element) {
  if(!is_array($element))
    $element=strtolower($element);
  if ( ($element === $search_for) || (is_array($element) && multi_array_search($search_for, $element)) ){
      return true;
  }
}
return false;
}
$arr = array("2014", array("January", "February", "March"), "2015", array("Monday", "Tuesday"));
echo multi_array_search("TUESDAY", $arr) ? 'Found' : 'Not found';
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support