# in_array does not find value

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 161162806
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 161736574
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [video_id] => 156382678
        )    
)
```

I try to find a value, but even though it's in the array it doesn't find it.

```
if(in_array("161162806", $safe, true)) {      
 echo "approved video";
  } else { 
  echo "non-approved video";
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you have arrays in array (multidimensional array).

You have to loop over :

```
foreach($safe as $s) {

if(in_array("161162806", $s)) {      
 echo "approved video";
  } else { 
  echo "non-approved video";
 }
}
```

PS : Remove `true` param if you want to assimilate integers and strings :

123 or "123"

Comment: You're welcome. Please, valid an answer (mine or DevDonkey's)

Answer (score 0):

you have declared a 'strict' check on [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

Because of this it will check the type as well. Seeing as your search parameter is a string, it wont match the integer in the array.

try this (when you've sorted the below mentioned issue):

```
if(in_array("161162806", $safe)) {      
   echo "approved video";
} else { 
   echo "non-approved video";
}
```

but you have separate arrays in the one your'e checking.  `in_array` will only check the direct values of the array provided.  Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array) question for a possible solution to that part of the problem. (Or Delphines answer)

Comment: Thank you for your help!