# check whether a value exist in codeigniter result_array

Tags: php, codeigniter

model returned a result array

```
public function check($date,$route){
       $query3=$this->db->query("SELECT SEAT_NO FROM TICKET WHERE ROUTE='".$route."' AND DTE='".$date."' "); 
       return $query3->result_array();
}
```

in controller

```
$data=$this->booking_model->check($date,$route);
```

now i need to check whether a value/string(for example "A") exist in $data array. the below code is not working.

```
if (in_array("A", $data)){  
   //code
}else{
   //code
}
```

Comment: What's not working? Is 'A' actually being returned in the array?

Comment: CodeIgniter's `result_array()` returns a multi dimensional array, so `in_array()` won't work the way you are trying to use it. Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128377/248567) which should handle what you're after.