# How do I search if a value is in a range, inside a multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

It's a simple question, but puzzling me:

```
$myarray = array(
    array(10,20),
    array(299, 315),
    array(156, 199)
);
```

How do I check if given `$x` , lies in between, in any of those particular individual array values? I want to search each individual entry array.

For Example, I want to search, if `$x` is somewhere between: `10` to `20` and then between `299` to `315` and then between `156` to `199`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Yes, might be n that question has 155 UPVOTES, but it was not asked like this. Right ??

Comment: But, plz mind my question - lies in between. NOt 'contains'.

Comment: You will have to be more specific on what you are trying to accomplish here. What code have you tried so far?

Comment: @luna.romania Do you want to pass a variable to the arrays and see if it's between those values?

Comment: @Rimble I have updated my question. $x is any random value & i want to check if its value lies between, as i asked in questions last part.

Comment: @Ivar yes..always 2..so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function is_in_array_range($array, $search) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $min = min($value);
        $max = max($value);

        if ($search >= $min && $search <= $max) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$myarray = array(
    array(10,20),
    array(299, 315),
    array(156, 199)
);

is_in_array_range($myarray, 9);  // Returns false
is_in_array_range($myarray, 11); // Returns true
```

The function `is_in_array_range()` will take two arguments. The array, and the value you want to check is in the range.

When it enters, it will loop over all elements in the array. Every time it gets the highest and lowest value of the nested array ([`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) and [`max()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php) function), and checks if the value you are looking for is between them. If this is the case, return true (this also stops the function). If true is never reached, the value is not found, so at the end of the function, return false.

Comment: Good approach, I had something similar coming up but not much use posting the same thing twice. Didn't think about using min and max for the values. Also the answer would be complete for the OP with some clarification on what you did exactly.

Comment: @Rimble Good call.

Comment: @ivar Awesome approach. Can someone upvote my question please :)

Comment: @luna.romania It's not really a well formulated question, there is little code shown where you actually try and find your desired result. Overall not something that I would personally upvote. Have you read [How-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Also adding in _UNIQUE IDEA_ in the title doesn't contribute to your question.

Answer (score 0):

this will do it code

```
foreach($myarray as $value)
{
if(in_array("10", $value, true))
{
    echo "Got 10";
}
}
```

Comment: Hi, M not searching for 10 & 20, but searching if $x is 10,11,12...19,20