# Filter rows of a 3d array where keys in a specific column satisfy a flat whitelist array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, whitelist

I need to filter a 3 dimensional array by the keys in one of its columns.  I wish to retain any row which has contains all required keys from a declared whitelist array.

Sample Data:

```
[
    [
        'name' => 'Фізика',
        'disciplines' => [
            1 => 'Українська мова та література',
            4 => 'Математика',
            5 => 'Фізика',
            6 => 'Біологія',
        ],
        'priority' => [
            1 => 0,
            4 => 1,
            5 => 2,
            6 => 2,
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Інформатика',
        'disciplines' => [
            1 => 'Українська мова та література',
            2 => 'Історія України',
            4 => 'Математика',
            12 => 'Іноземна мова',
        ],
        'priority' => [
            1 => 0,
            2 => 2,
            4 => 1,
            12 => 2,
        ]
    ],
    [
        'name' => 'Початкова освіта',
        'disciplines' => [
            1 => 'Українська мова та література',
            2 => 'Історія України',
        ],
        'priority' => [
            1 => 0,
            2 => 2,
        ]
    ],
]
```

I want to keep rows where their discipline array contains keys for all values in my flat array:

```
[2, 4, 12]
```

`in_array()` is not working for me.  How can I filter this array structure using this array of required keys?  From my sample data, only the second row should be kept.

[var_dump() of larger array](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a02921c602840026d04585c7c7751423)

Comment: question is unclear.... where is disciplines defined...?

Comment: in_array() not for multidimensional array in php ....

Comment: @Naincy, I need to get an answer true or false, if there is a set of disciplines in the array.
For example: $disciplines[2, 4, 12];

Comment: @AmanKumar I know about this I ask, can you know analogue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @Sojtin, this is not a decision for me, thank you for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Prepare your whitelist so that the required values are the keys of a flat array.
- Call `array_filter()` to iterate each row of the sample array.
- Try to eliminate as many elements from the whitelist array using the row's discipline keys.  If there are none remaining, then the row satisfies the whitelist and should be retained.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/hQT7R))

```
$get['disciplines'] = ['second' => 2, 'third' => 4, 'fourth' => 12];
$filterBy = array_flip($get['disciplines']);

var_export(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        fn($row) => !array_diff_key($filterBy, $row['disciplines'])
    )
);
```

Comment: It looks like a solution to my problem. But, I found myself the answer to your question! Thank you for the answer!