# PHP string search in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, string-search

I have just started poking around PHP (new to PHP) coding related to Pinterest. I am stuck on doing a string search against multidimensional arrays. I did a lot of research and tried out different things but was not able to find much help on string search against multidimensional arrays.

Specifically, **I have tried recursive array search** from this post: **[in_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)** and but it didn't work for me. Perhaps I am doing something wrong, which why I am here to seek out some PHP experts help.

When I run it against my multidimensional array (*mentioned below*) I get the answer found every single time and doesn't matter what string I specify.

For example: If I run the below code, and it says found, although it should say not found because there is to **Irix** word in my multidimensional array.

```
echo in_array_r("Irix", $info) ? 'found' : 'not found';
```

Below is my multidimensional array:

```
$info = array
(
    "origin_pinner" => null,
    "domain" => "teacherspayteachers.com",
    "done_by_me" => null,
    "videos" => null,
    "tracking_params" => "CwABAAAADDk0NzI0ODYzODc2OAA",
    "aggregated_pin_data" => array
        (
            "comment_count" => 0,
            "did_it_data" => array
                (
                    "recommend_scores" => array
                        (
                            "0" => array
                                (
                                    "count" => 0,
                                    "score" => 1,
                                ),
                            "1" => array
                                (
                                    "count" => 0,
                                    "score" => 0.5,
                                ),
                            "2" => array
                                (
                                    "count" => 0,
                                    "score" => 0,
                                ),
                        ),
                    "rating" => -1,
                    "user_count" => 1,
                    "tags" => array
                        (
                        ),
                    "images_count" => 1,
                    "recommended_count" => 1,
                    "details_count" => 1,
                    "type" => "aggregateddiditdata",
                ),
            "id" => 4894650307138568743,
            "is_shop_the_look" => null,
            "aggregated_stats" => array
                (
                    "saves" => 13580,
                    "done" => 1,
                ),
        ),
    "hashtags" => array
        (
        ),
    "like_count" => 0,
    "images" => array
        (
            "736x" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/736x/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 736,
                    "height" => 1380,
                ),
            "60x60" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/60x60/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 60,
                    "height" => 60,
                ),
            "474x" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/474x/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 474,
                    "height" => 888,
                ),
            "170x" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/170x/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 170,
                    "height" => 318,
                ),
            "600x315" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/600x315/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 600,
                    "height" => 315,
                ),
            "564x" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/564x/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 564,
                    "height" => 1057,
                ),
            "236x" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/236x/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 236,
                    "height" => 442,
                ),
            "136x136" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/136x136/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.jpg",
                    "width" => 136,
                    "height" => 136,
                ),
            "orig" => array
                (
                    "url" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/6c/a8/8e/6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3.png",
                    "width" => 768,
                    "height" => 1440,
                ),
        ),
    "id" => "AdJy70aUUiIeIp2s5VM5ulcoVr6xDsV_ff3K0oJCVQr-MoRBPMbAVRE",
    "closeup_user_note" => "FREE Teaching Resource   Editable Novel Brochure on Google Classroom that students can edit for any novel!",
    "category" => "education",
    "price_currency" => "USD",
    "is_promoted" => null,
    "description_html" => "FREE Teaching Resource   Editable Novel Brochure on Google Classroom that students can edit for any novel!",
    "per_pin_analytics" => array
        (
            "id" => "<Pin 448671181617679376>",
        ),
    "section" => null,
    "buyable_product" => null,
    "access" => array
        (
        ),
    "is_promotable" => null,
    "comment_count" => 1,
    "board" => array
        (
            "category" => null,
            "is_collaborative" => null,
            "layout" => "default",
            "description" => null,
            "privacy" => "public",
            "url" => "/rhythmsandtwine/novel-studies/",
            "image_cover_url" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/200x150/17/3a/ab/173aab4ddb8d48f4d50002c1f95f6d22.jpg",
            "pin_thumbnail_urls" => array
                (
                    "0" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/150x150/d8/a3/34/d8a334af515fab7e5f73a15e5244f8ac.jpg",
                    "1" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/150x150/3f/4c/50/3f4c50eded7a107b4a49dea3c58a7848.jpg",
                    "2" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/150x150/04/67/ee/0467eead4aba47f47bb910a48cd1afdd.jpg",
                    "3" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/150x150/8f/90/af/8f90afe949fa0ef24d6a5a9bc85d2537.jpg",
                    "4" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/150x150/bf/ff/a5/bfffa5392c1f7c2317cd3e1cf2aa9920.jpg",
                ),
            "image_thumbnail_url" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/upload/448671250316290197_board_thumbnail_2017-12-27-08-38-39_92111_60.jpg",
            "access" => array
                (
                ),
            "collaborated_by_me" => null,
            "owner" => array
                (
                    "id" => 448671319035224306,
                ),
            "map_id" => "pinterest.ijz1714i",
            "followed_by_me" => null,
            "type" => "board",
            "id" => "448671250316290197",
            "name" => "Novel Studies",
        ),
    "link_domain" => array
        (
            "official_user" => null,
        ),
    "type" => "pin",
    "method" => "uploaded",
    "image_signature" => "6ca88ebc09648b14a88b125144993ef3",
    "attribution" => null,
    "description" => "FREE Teaching Resource   Editable Novel Brochure on Google Classroom that students can edit for any novel!",
    "price_value" => 0,
    "liked_by_me" => null,
    "show_personalize_field" => null,
    "title" => null,
    "native_creator" => null,
    "is_playable" => null,
    "rich_metadata" => array
        (
            "site_name" => "Teachers Pay Teachers",
            "description" => "Novel Brochure - Pamphlet for Google Classroom Freebie! This resource allows students to create a pamphlet that can be edited for ANY novel! The file contains a Google Drive link that can be used for Google Classroom. **Be sure to MAKE A COPY of the link and save to your",
            "link_status" => 0,
            "title" => "Novel Brochure Google Classroom Freebie",
            "locale" => "en",
            "has_price_drop" => null,
            "amp_url" => null,
            "id" => "301b4d97d46163d2c9e3b22de2f0a345",
            "url" => "https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Novel-Brochure-Google-Classroom-Freebie-3104649",
            "tracker" => null,
            "apple_touch_icon_link" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/e102b188545e64e45a326583a64a6bc332be2df9228a3f99685af702.png?155fe47b3e0bb98f4d90a12033216561",
            "favicon_images" => array
                (
                    "50x" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/50x/b95b678fa3287d329190f918cefbbac4a5a3e65a0212bc32f9e2c363.png?3eb3040f733c42a12569d94d396a07a4",
                    "orig" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/b95b678fa3287d329190f918cefbbac4a5a3e65a0212bc32f9e2c363.ico?3eb3040f733c42a12569d94d396a07a4",
                ),
            "type" => "richpindataview",
            "amp_valid" => null,
            "apple_touch_icon_images" => array
                (
                    "50x" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/50x/318e68afb755008848f5ec59beac068e50c4696d4f11e51552cd2271.png?d99a7f242e13fff1cd16b9b5de22ec0b",
                    "orig" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/318e68afb755008848f5ec59beac068e50c4696d4f11e51552cd2271.png?d99a7f242e13fff1cd16b9b5de22ec0b",
                ),
            "favicon_link" => "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/09f765214b80be5f5198899864e6996540ed8a4e54fee82ce58fd606.ico?fbf2fa4d283a37a435dde24f48537e7d",
        ),
    "via_pinner" => array
        (
            "username" => "dezi4462",
            "first_name" => "Dezi",
            "domain_url" => null,
            "twitter_url" => null,
            "domain_verified" => null,
            "image_medium_url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/75x75_RS/f2/61/06/f261063238cc0672f1eb586352660452.jpg",
            "explicitly_followed_by_me" => null,
            "is_default_image" => null,
            "location" => null,
            "full_name" => "Dezi Martinez",
            "indexed" => null,
            "verified_identity" => array
                (
                ),
            "image_small_url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/30x30_RS/f2/61/06/f261063238cc0672f1eb586352660452.jpg",
            "followed_by_me" => null,
            "type" => "user",
            "id" => "375417456346283592",
        ),
    "link" => "https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Novel-Brochure-Google-Classroom-Freebie-3104649",
    "has_required_attribution_provider" => null,
    "is_repin" => 1,
    "rich_recipe_top_ingredients" => array
        (
        ),
    "buyable_product_availability" => null,
    "pinner" => array
        (
            "username" => "rhythmsandtwine",
            "first_name" => "Jennifer",
            "domain_url" => null,
            "twitter_url" => null,
            "domain_verified" => null,
            "image_medium_url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/75x75_RS/ae/c0/ac/aec0acd834181d845ee39e437dbd939c.jpg",
            "explicitly_followed_by_me" => null,
            "is_default_image" => null,
            "location" => null,
            "full_name" => "Jennifer Forbes",
            "indexed" => null,
            "verified_identity" => array
                (
                ),
            "image_small_url" => "https://i.pinimg.com/30x30_RS/ae/c0/ac/aec0acd834181d845ee39e437dbd939c.jpg",
            "followed_by_me" => null,
            "type" => "user",
            "id" => 448671319035224306,
        ),
    "repin_count" => 354,
    "tracked_link" => "https://www.teacherspayteachers.com/Product/Novel-Brochure-Google-Classroom-Freebie-3104649",
    "created_at" => "Fri, 09 Jun 2017 23:54:29 +0000",
    "is_native" => null,
    "native_pin_stats" => null,
    "promoter" => null,
    "pin360" => null,
    "privacy" => "public",
    "dominant_color" => "#859886",
    "promoted_is_removable" => null,
    "embed" => null,
    "is_quick_promotable" => null,
    "is_video" => null,
    "closeup_description" => null
);
```

Comment: in_array() does not work on multidimensional arrays

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: @D.'s he is actually using the exact function of the related question but writes that doesn't work

Comment: @Paolo I think he should try all answers and tell us if they worked or not.He has tried an answer from 8 years ago

Comment: @D.'s he actually tried the function of the accepted answer with score of 399 (at the time of writing)

Comment: @Paolo Okay and if what he is searching is answered there?

Comment: @D.'s and Paolo I have tried all the answers guys.

Comment: @LT- you should make reference to that question,anyway time will prove it

Comment: Hi @D.'s, I did post the reference the first time I posted my question. You might have missed it.

Comment: @LT- YesI missed it edited 10 min ago.Gimme me a break!

Comment: @D.'s I was trying to improve and clarify my question while watching comments. 

You can see the full history of my question yourself here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48888350/revisions). Scroll all the way down.

Comment: @LT- found the issue and proposed a solution. Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, I left some "debugging" code in my answer. Just fixed.

Comment: @D.'s the result observed by the OP is due to PHP type juggling when doing weak comparison. It's easy to fix: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889719/1579327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result you're getting is due PHP's type juggling when weak-comparing values of different type.

Try this, for example:

```
$x = ('Irix' == 0 );
var_export( $x );
```

You get `TRUE` !

Why?

`'Irix'` is converted into `int`, after conversion is `0` so compares true with `0`.

In your array you have several values set to `0` so that's why `Irix` is apparently found.

You should use **strict** comparison when calling the function:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

If you need to use weak comparison (in order to match `123 == '123'` for example) you may tweak the function to cast number to strings whend doing weak comparison:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        // cast $item to string if numeric when doing weak comparison
        if( ! $strict && is_string( $needle ) && ( is_float( $item ) || is_int( $item ) ) ) {
            $item = (string)$item;
        }
        // ----------------------------------------------------------

        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Finally, if you need to evaluate true sub-string matches too (ex. find `"example"` into the string `"this is a example"`) the function is this:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        // cast $item to string if numeric when doing weak comparison
        if( ! $strict && is_string( $needle ) && ( is_float( $item ) || is_int( $item ) ) ) {
            $item = (string)$item;
        }
        // ----------------------------------------------------------

        // Substring search
        if( is_string( $needle ) && is_string( $item ) && strpos( $item, $needle ) !== false ) {
            return true;
        }
        // ----------------

        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Compete demo code is available [**here**](https://pastebin.com/55gqYHPV)

Comment: Hi @Paolo, Thank you very much for answering. From the strict comparison, do you mean to set $strict to true or using `===` instead of `==` in the function? I have tried setting $strict = true then the function returns not found every time, even when searching for Google, which is in the array. I have also tried both of you suggested functions and still getting the same results.

Comment: @LT strict comparison `===` requires that the values are of the same type: ex. `123 === "123"` evaluates `false` because the left term is a number while the right term is a string. --- You do not find `"Google"` because you don't have a value `"Google"`. You have values that **contain** `Google` like "`Visit Google"` but `"Google" == "Visit Google"` evaluates `false`. They are two totally different srings. --- **Do you need to do sub-string search?**

Comment: @LT- I added a version of the function that does sub-string search in case that's what you need

Comment: Yes I am looking to find out if I can any of the values in the array contain google in them.  Since in the array I have `
[rich_metadata] => Array
        (
            [site_name] => Teachers Pay Teachers
            [description] => Novel Brochure - Pamphlet for Google `

there is word google in it and I want to make sure the function returns true.

Comment: I have tried the second example:
`// ----------------------------------------------------------`
`// Substring search`
`if( is_string( $needle ) && is_string( $item ) && strpos( $item, $needle ) !== false ) {`
`return true;`
`}`
`// ----------------`
`if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {`
`//return true;`
`}`
`}`
`return false;`
`}`

Comment: @LT- the last function in my answer does what you ask. I tried it with "Google" on the array you posted in the question and works.

Comment: I might be missing something then. Do I keep `if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) { return true;}` if I am using `if( is_string( $needle ) && is_string( $item ) && strpos( $item, $needle ) !== false ) {     return true;}`?  Also, have you tried searching for word that is not in the array? If I use your last function as is then I get true value even if I use a random word that is not in the array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165514/discussion-between-lt-and-paolo).

Comment: @LT- I tried the function and it works fine. Copy-paste the entire function (the last one) from my answer. The complete code I tried with (it includes the array you posted) is available here: https://pastebin.com/55gqYHPV

Comment: The code works well for me!  Thanks for the question and the answer!  Saved me pulling out my hair for hours!