# How can I check if a value exists in my array?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm quite new to PHP... I am trying to check if a value exists in my `$Session array` and then display the content according to that but it is always showing 'Match not found' even when I know the value does exist in the array.

This is a `print_r` of my array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => SIEMENS 
        [1] => 523-096-32 
        [2] => 1
        [3] => New 
    ) 
)
```

When I do:

```
$array = $_SESSION['arr'];

if( in_array( "523-096-32" , $array ) ){
    echo "Match found";
}else{
    echo "Match not found";
}
```

The result is "Match not found".

I have also tried replacing `in_array` with `array_key_exists` but I'm having the same result.

My question is: where am I going wrong and how can I fix it to display "Match found"? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `in_array` only checks one level deep, your value is in a nested array so you'd need to do `in_array( "523-096-32" , $array[0] )` to find it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: array_key_exists is for key not for value. [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Answer (score -1):

Using `in_array("523-096-32", $array[0])` as the comment on your question indicates will work, but it may not be the best solution depending on what `$_SESSION['arr']` is supposed to do. The best way to check for that value depends on whether or not `$_SESSION['arr']` is supposed to be a multidimensional array.

It looks like the array inside `$_SESSION['arr']` is a set of values representing a single item. If `$_SESSION['arr']` is meant to hold a group of those items, although there's only one in the example you showed, looking in `$array[0]` will only check the first item. Instead you can iterate it and check each item for that value until you find it (or not).

```
$found = false;
foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $item) {
    if ($item[1] === "523-096-32") {
        $found = true;
        break;
    }
}
echo $found ? 'Match found' : 'Match not found';
```

If the items inside `$_SESSION['arr']` aren't consistently structured, referring to `$item[1]` won't be accurate and you should use `in_array` instead.

```
if (in_array("523-096-32", $item)) { ...
```

If `$_SESSION['arr']` is only one level deep, you shouldn't need to use a recursive function to find a match.

---

On the other hand, if `$_SESSION['arr']` is only meant to be one array, rather than an array with another array in it like you have, you probably assigned it incorrectly, like

```
$_SESSION['arr'][] = ['SIEMENS', '523-096-32', '1', 'New'];
```

instead of

```
$_SESSION['arr'] = ['SIEMENS', '523-096-32', '1', 'New'];
```

If you assign it directly like the second example here, using `in_array` like you tried to do will work.

Comment: Hmm, whoever downvoted, is there something incorrect or inaccurate in the answer, or did you just think the question should be closed instead of answered? If it's the second thing I can understand why you wouldn't want to say anything, but if not I'd like to know if I made a mistake.

Comment: No offense, but don't see how this could help OP. You are replacing the nice and short in_array() with a inflexible foreach-loop, pointing to a fixed array index. This kinda make the simple "bug" more complicated than it is, doesn't it? Cheers! (I'm the downvoter, sorry, slow in writing... ;))

So, to be "constructive": I would stick with the in_array solution and maybe offer an recursive function. This would help in most possible cases.

Comment: No offense taken, thanks for commenting. I just thought that based on the values in the inner array it seemed likely that `$_SESSION['arr'][1]` etc. could also exist at some point, and if that was the case, a single `in_array` would no longer suffice. And if that _wasn't_ the case, it shouldn't have been multidimensional in the first place and that should be fixed instead of looking at the pointless `[0]`. Then again, I do have a tendency to to overthink things :-)

Comment: But I'm not arguing with your vote. I appreciate that there are different opinions on things.