# Get array values that differ

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with 2 PHP arrays.

```
print_r($matches);
print_r($dexcode_comp);
```

`$matches` and `dexcode_comp`.

Their outcomes are as follow:

$matches:

```
{
    0: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "BeS712210",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "BeS712210"
    },
    1: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "BeS712210",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "BeS712210"
    },
    2: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "BeS712210",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "BeS712210"
    },
    3: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "S-T41471",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "S-T41471"
    },
    4: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "Ron35844",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "Ron35844"
    },
    5: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "Lin10961",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "Lin10961"
    },
    6: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "Tip295926",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "Tip295926"
    },
    7: {
        simplicate_dexcode: "Lin10961",
        callmonkey_dexcode: "Lin10961"
    }
},
```

$dexcode_comp:

```
{
    0: {
        dexcode: "BeS712210"
    },
    1: {
        dexcode: "De 48245"
    },
    2: {
        dexcode: "Bis1016338"
    },
    3: {
        dexcode: "S-T41471"
    },
    4: {
        dexcode: "Ron35844"
    },
    5: {
        dexcode: "Lin10961"
    },
    6: {
        dexcode: "Tip295926"
    },
    7: {
        dexcode: "Lin10961"
    },
    8: {
        dexcode: "SLN893827"
    },
    9: {
        dexcode: "Fen1016241"
    },
    10: {
        dexcode: "Aut331661"
    },
    11: {
        dexcode: "Pro39613"
    },
    12: {
        dexcode: "Com920158"
    },
    13: {
        dexcode: "Sma21322"
    },
    14: {
        dexcode: "Aut331661"
    },
    15: {
        dexcode: "Pro39613"
    },
    16: {
        dexcode: "Com920158"
    },
    17: {
        dexcode: "Sma21322"
    }
}
```

From the array `$dexcode_comp` I wish to return all the values that don't appear in `$matches`. Like the opposite of an `array_intersect` function.

What can I do to achieve this? I hope someone can push me in the right direction.

Comment: Those are objects.

Comment: @Script47 give me a second, its because of this chrome extension im using. Turns arrays into objects. let me fix it lol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in\_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: **SO is not a free coding service**. The idea is supposed to be... **YOU** code something to match your requirements and **THEN if** you get problems you ask a question about a specific coding problem here.

Comment: @RiggsFolly did i ask for code? I literally asked push me in the rigth direction.

Comment: Its also not a tutorial site

Comment: So asking for a hint in the right direction is asking for a tutorial now? @RiggsFolly

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array-diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
$result = array_diff($matches, $dexcode_comp);
```

This will compare the first array with the second and return an array with the values that are not in common. As you said the opposite of `array_intersect`

Answer (score 1):

Those are objects, not arrays, so you can use `json_encode` and `json_decode` with the second parameter as `true` to make then into associative arrays and then use `array_diff_assoc`:

```
$arr1 = json_decode(json_encode($obj1), true);
$arr2 = json_decode(json_encode($obj2), true);
$diff = array_diff_assoc($arr1, $arr2);
```

**Note:** There is also a [`array_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) if you are interested.

**Reading Material**

[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

[`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

[`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)