# How to catch these PHP Warnings?

Tags: php

After reading about the **...** splat operator here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56634367/429523

I decided to do this:

```
if (isset($some_array) && is_array($some_array)) {
    if (in_array($needle, array_merge(...$some_array), true)) {
        // do stuff...
    }
}
```

I'm receiving warnings like this:

`PHP Warning:  array_merge() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given in...`

`PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in...`

How are these warnings getting past the isset / is_array if condition?

Comment: __Empty array__ (`array()` or `[]`) is __isset__ and is __array__.

Comment: use `if (!empty($some_array)` if that's what you actually mean; The answer to the asked question is you don't catch them

Comment: You could use `array_merge([], ...$some_array)` to ensure that there's always at least 1 argument.

Comment: @AD7six - yes, I believe that other question answers mine. Using !empty instead of isset resolved this for me.