# Trying to compare a string to an array using strpos but not working

Tags: php

I want to compare a variable called $value to items in a multidimensional array called $listofplaces. So when a user uploads a file I can validate it and see if it matches exactly to what’s in my array.

My $lisofplaces Array looks like this when printed (I haven’t added all the places as there are many):

```
array(3){
[0] =>
   array(18){ 
     [“type”] => “FIELD”
      …
     [“values”] =>
     array(50)
     [1] => 
         array(3) {
         [“name”] => “Paris”
          …}
     [2] => 
         array(3) {
         [“name”] => “London”
          …}
   }
}
```

my method to compare my variable to the array

```
if(strpos($value, $listofplaces) !== false){
       echo ‘found’;} else{ echo ‘not found’;}
```

However this isn’t working and I don’t understand why please help:
Also I know the quotation marks are wrong I am doing this off my iPad

Comment: You can not compare string to array in php.
[Here is the solution you need](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128377/9026411)

Comment: There are many ways of doing this but they all require a bit more code than that