# PHP check if array contains value from array with different key

Tags: php

I have this array:

```
$term = array();
```

For example:

```
$common_item = array('id' => 0, 'full_name' => 'my great name'); //etc
$first_item = array('name' => 'Robert', 'item' => $common_item);

$second_item = array('name' => 'Roberto', 'item' => $common_item);

$term[] = $first_item;
//check if terms already has an item with the same item(common_item) and don't add
$term[] = $second_item;
```

So both items in term have the same 'item' value. How can i check if term item already has the same item in terms array before adding?

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what went wrong?

Comment: Not entirely sure what logic you're trying to implement. Please share actual outcome vs. desired outcome (edit question). And show us what you've tried already, your best attempt, you might be closer to a solution than you think.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with `in_array()` function ?

```
 <?php
   $os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
    if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
    }
    if (in_array("mac", $os)) {
    echo "Got mac";
   }
 ?>
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

#### Edit: Possible duplicate ###  [in_array() and multidimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array)

Comment: Two items have the same 'item' value but not 'name' value so in_array will return false

Comment: OK, I got it. It is possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array .