# Adding to array if value doesnt exist

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array built from a log file and I want to create a new array containing only the player names.

$list[2] is the location of the player names

```
             if(preg_match_all('/^(.*?) Player "(.*)" (.*) /m', $open, $list))
                {
                     foreach($list[2] as $name)
                     {
                        if(!in_array($name,$players))
                        {
                         $players[] = ["Player"=>$name];
                        }
                     }
                 }
                var_dump($players);
```

Its adding the player names to the array however it is adding even if an entry exists with the name as a value.

** Answer **
Was resolved following suggested answer by using

```
  $gt = array_unique($list[2]);
    foreach($gt as $name)
     {
      $players[] = ["Player"=>$name];
     }
```

Comment: `$players[$name] = TRUE;` could work.. doesn't seem like `Player` would be needed.

Comment: Your current issue is documented here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Comment: This duplicate question does not represent a good "signpost" because there is no [mcve].  The intention is clear enough for programmers that understand your code, but having sample input and exact desired output would be better from a content quality point of view.  Please never [edit] your question to include an "answer" -- that is not the job of a question.  You can avoid calling `array_unique()` if you do an associative push `$players[$name] = ["Player" => $name];` because duplicate keys on the same level of an array are not allowed (they will be overwritten).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `array_unique` function
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
             if(preg_match_all('/^(.*?) Player "(.*)" (.*) /m', $open, $list))
                {
                     foreach($list[2] as $name)
                     {
                         $players[] = ["Player"=>$name];
                     }
                 }
                $players=array_unique($players);
                var_dump($players);
```

other solution:

```
             if(preg_match_all('/^(.*?) Player "(.*)" (.*) /m', $open, $list))
                {
                     foreach($list[2] as $name)
                     {
                        if(!in_array(["Player"=>$name],$players))
                        {
                         $players[] = ["Player"=>$name];
                        }
                     }
                 }
                $players=array_unique($players);
                var_dump($players);
```

Comment: Please flag/vote to close duplicate questions instead of answering them.  When you answer duplicate questions, you make it harder for the Roomba to do its important work.  I need to take this moment to spoil the romance -- in 2022, when someone asks a basic question, there are usually at least 5 duplicates to choose from.  So, again, please do not answer basic duplicate questions.